# Include only certain libraries on an operating system

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

When writing an app that one wants to have compile on mac, linux and windows, what is the best way of managing the different libraries that will need to be included on the various operating systems. For example, using the glut opengl toolkit requires different includes on each operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is actually two questions in one:

1) How do I write my C++ code to include the right include files on the right platform?

2) How do I write my Makefile to work on different platforms?

The C++ code question is already answered - find the platform-specific defines and use them to figure out what platform you're on.

Automake or scons are quite complex, and are worth your time only if you intend to release your code to a wide audience. In the case of in-house code, a "generic" makefile with per-platform include is usually sufficient. For Windows, you can get GNU Make for Windows (available from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/), or use nmake and limit yourself to the subset of syntax common between all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to worry about header files, then the preprocessor will do everything you need. If you want to handle differing source files, and possibly different libraries you'll need a tool to handle it.

Some options include:

- [The Autotools](http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/)
- [Scons](http://www.scons.org/)
- [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)

My personal favorite is CMake. The Autotools uses a multi-stage process that's relatively easy to break, and scons just feels weird to me. Cmake will also generate project files for a variety of IDEs, in addition to makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on [Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96196/when-are-c-macros-benificial). One of the answers how to use conditional compilation based on OS/COmpiler (its near the top).

The use of the Autoconfiguration tools is a nice addition on top of this but is not needed for small projects where it may be easier to detect the OS explicitly, though for larger projects that may need to run on many different types of OS you should also explore the Available autoconfiguration tools mentioned by [Branan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116535/what-is-the-best-way-to-only-include-certain-libraries-on-certain-operating-sys#116664)

Answer (score 0):

Several projects I've worked on use an autoconf-based configure script which builds a Makefile, hence the reason you can build all of them from source with a simple:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

[Scons](http://scons.org) has a configuring mechanism that will do a lot of what autotools do without as much complexity, and is pretty darn portable (although not as portable as autotools).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should have a set of preprocessor symbols it will provide that you can use.  For example **linux** for gcc on a Linux system, _WIN32 for VC++.  If you need something more complex then look at [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), but that works best for Unix based code.

I'd recommend checking out how some of the larger OpenSource projects handle this. See [AutoSense.hpp](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xerces/c/branches/xerces-2/src/xercesc/util/AutoSense.hpp?view=markup) from (an old release of) Apache Xerces.

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries offer the same API on the different platforms, I would create a "proxy" include file containing all the necessary `#ifdef`s.  That 'platform-independent' include file is then included in your client code instead of cluttering it with numerous and ugly-reading preprocessor commands.  These will be contained in the ugly and cluttered platform-independent include.

If the API differs across platforms, you will need to create your own abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a cop-out answer, but have you looked at how boost handles this?  They build on quite a few platforms without autoconf, although they do have their *own* build system - bjam - that probably handles some of the same situations.  They also do a nice auto-linking trick on windows that automatically selects the right version of libraries for linking depending on the version of the MSVC compiler. Based on your initial description, it sounds like just macro defs checking for various platforms/compilers might do the trick, but perhaps there is more to your problem that would prevent this.

Comment: They use the preprocessor and the MSVC pragma-based auto-linker to handle linking on Windows, IIRC