# Next or previous enum

Tags: c#, enums

Given an enum that has assigned values, what is the best way to get the next or previous enum given a value. For example, consider this enum:

```
public enum TimeframeType {
    None = 0,
    [Description("1 month")]
    Now = 30,
    [Description("1-3 months")]
    Short = 90,
    [Description("3-6 months")]
    Medium = 180,
    [Description("6+ months")]
    Long = 360
}
```

Is there a good way create a function that would do EnumPrevious(TimeframeType.Short) returns TimeframeType.Now and EnumNext(TimeframeType.Short) would return TimeframeType.Medium?

I already wrote an ugly implementation of EnumNext but I'm not convinced that it is the best way to do so. I'm hoping someone else has already tackled this problem.

```
public static T EnumNext<T>(T value) where T : struct {
    T[] values = (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
        if (object.Equals(value, values[i])) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i >= values.Length - 1) {
        return values[values.Length - 1];
    } else {
        return values[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good example of using the wrong tool for the job - hence my upvote. Thanks for posting a good question. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to solve the wrong problem. This is far too complex for a simple enum to calculate.  Refactor the enum to a class and use a comparison interface.

If this route is open to you look at how this *could* be implemented by a class:

```
public class TimeFrame: IComparable
{
   private int days;

   public int Days
   {
        set 
        {
             days = value;
        }
   }

   public int CompareTo(object other)
   {
        //see this for implementation -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText
   }


   public string Description
   {
       get code to return the description string , ie "1-3 months"
   }

}
```

Comment: Ah, that is a much better approach. That class has been an enum for a long time and when adding new functionality I tried to extend instead of refactor. Thanks for the whack on the head :)

Comment: Just wanted to add, there is also an IComparable<T> interface for those copying the code sample above that will let you not have to check the CompareTo's type.

Answer (score 2):

Enums in .NET aren't really meant to be ordered, so you shouldn't rely on it. Someone else later might just come and add a value somewhere in the middle that would be out of order. Thus there also isn't such a functionality built in. You can write your own functions (similar to what you have already written) but that's completely up to you. I would also adivse you do the sorting by yourself in your method and not rely on .NET to keep the items "sorted".

**Added:** That, and I also second the opinion that you should choose another data structure.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not built in way to do this, and your solution looks just dandy - assuming that an enum is the right construct to use here...

I do think that you're trying to do a bit to much with an enum.  Perhaps TimeframeType should be a class or should there be a static array of Timeframe data?

(just saw Jimmy's post - looks like we have a similar opinion).

Answer (score 0):

**Note this only works if you don't care about the values of the enum and just want them ordered**

If you can do change the enum I would do the following

```
public enum TimeframeType {
    None = 0,
    [Description("1 month")]

    TimeFrameStep = 30,
    [Description("Step from previous to next")]

    Now = None + TimeFrameStep,
    [Description("1-3 months")]
    
    Short = Now + TimeFrameStep,
    [Description("3-6 months")]

    Medium = Now + TimeFrameStep,
    [Description("6+ months")]
    
    Long = Medium + TimeFrameStep,
    [Description("12 months")]
}
```

Then I would loop from Now to Long by incrementing the incrementer by TimeFrameStep.

Answer (score 0):

See the question [Enum in C++ like Enum in Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300592/enum-in-c-like-enum-in-ada) for information on what Ada does - and, despite what's written in comments there, I don't think it is trivial to provide the same functionality in C, C++, nor (I think) in C# or Java unless those systems provide the help automatically.