# Number of elements in an enum

Tags: c, enums

In C, is there a nice way to track the number of elements in an enum? I've seen

```
enum blah {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD,
    LAST
};
```

But this only works if the items are sequential and start at zero.

Comment: See the question on [`enum` in C++ like `enum` in Ada](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300592/enum-in-c-like-enum-in-ada).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I don't believe there is. But what would you do with such a number if they are not sequential, and you don't already have a list of them somewhere? And if they are sequential but start at a different number, you could always do:

```
enum blah {
    FIRST = 128,
    SECOND,
    THIRD,
    END
};
const int blah_count = END - FIRST;
```

Comment: can enum types be negative?  If so watch out with this one.

Comment: FIRST=-2 would still calculate correctly, I think: 1 - (-2) = 3.

Comment: No need to watch out; subtraction works just fine for negative numbers. Pax has it right.

Comment: FIRST = -200, SECOND = -199, THIRD = -198, END = -100.  -200 - (-100) = bad news

Comment: I meant sequential as in you only ever set the first value, and let each remaining value increment by default, in sequence. enum blah { FIRST= <any-number>, SECOND, THIRD, END };

Comment: like i am saying thought setting the first to -9 and having 3 elements -9 - (-7) = -2.  You need an absolute value or something.

Comment: No, you would get FIRST = -9 SECOND = -8 THIRD = -7 END = -6, so you'd have -6 - (-9) = -6 + 9 = 3

Comment: No problem; an easy mistake to make.

Comment: @Brian: the value END could be useful if FIRST=0 and values are used as indexes for a static array (for example a static array of strings describing the values). Then the array can be declared and defined with size 'END', thus no need to change its size each time a value is added to the enum.

Comment: `enum {
 E_1 = 0,
 E_2 = 5,
 E_3,
 E_4,
 E_5 = 10,
 E_END 
};`, this will end of error!

Comment: I suggest editing the answer and add "the last being a placeholder that always designates the end of the list". Otherwise it's confusing.

Answer (score 84):

If you don't assign your enums you can do somethings like this:

```
enum MyType {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3,
  NumberOfTypes
}
```

NumberOfTypes will evaluate to 3 which is the number of real types.

Comment: Can you always be sure that in every C implementation anywhere at all times enums start from 0? I assume so, but is it always really true?

Comment: Late answer @JohnyTex, but the C standard mentions under 'Enumeration specifiers':  `If the first enumerator has
no =, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no =
defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by
adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant.` So yeah, this would apply to any standards-adhering implementation.

Comment: This can mess up with your switch statements if no default is provided

Answer (score 34):

Old question, I know. This is for the googlers with the same question.

You could use [X-Macros](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387)

Example:

```
//The values are defined via a map which calls a given macro which is defined later
#define ENUM_MAP(X) \
      X(VALA, 0)    \
      X(VALB, 10)   \
      X(VALC, 20)

//Using the map for the enum decl
#define X(n, v) [n] = v,
typedef enum val_list {
    ENUM_MAP(X) //results in [VALA] = 0, etc...
} val_list;
#undef X

//For the count of values
#define X(n, v) + 1
int val_list_count = 0 + ENUM_MAP(X); //evaluates to 0 + 1 + 1 + 1
#undef X
```

This is also transparent to an IDE, so auto-completes will work fine (as its all done in the pre-processor).

Comment: Awesome, I actually came here because I was looking for a good way to determine the _number_ of elements in an X_MACRO, and this is a good way.

Comment: You could also just take the number of elements in the `val_list` array by using the idiomatic `(sizeof val_list / sizeof val_list[0])`

Comment: It should probably be `n = v,` though,

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, no. There is not.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/712487/9691976

Comment: a better one? this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28164920/9691976

Comment: Only good answer, as the other answers all have restrictions and limitations.  And there is no use for the count - you can't use it to validate non-consecutive enums anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a very old question, but as the accepted answer is wrong, I feel compelled to post my own. I'll reuse the accepted answer's example, slightly modified.
(Making the assumption that enums are sequential.)

```
// Incorrect code, do not use!
enum blah {
  FIRST   =  0,
  SECOND, // 1
  THIRD,  // 2
  END     // 3
};
const int blah_count = END - FIRST;
// And this above would be 3 - 0 = 3, although there actually are 4 items.
```

Any developer knows the reason: `count = last - first + 1`.
And this works with any combination of signs (both ends negative, both positive, or only first end negative). You can try.

```
// Now, the correct version.
enum blah {
  FIRST   =  0,
  SECOND, // 1
  THIRD,  // 2
  END     // 3
};
const int blah_count = END - FIRST + 1; // 4
```

Edit: reading the text again, I got a doubt. Is that `END` meant not to be part of the offered items? That looks weird to me, but well, I guess it could make sense...

Comment: The intention is that there are 3 elements in the enum (`FIRST, SECOND & THIRD`), with the last being a placeholder that always designates the end of the list, so that if additional items are added it is not necessary to change the formula for the item count.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought when I read again a few hours later. Thanks for confirming. A comment next to `END` that says "Not mean to be used" or something might help understanding the code.

Comment: I like to use a convention something like "blah_end_marker"; the "end_marker" identifies the purpose, while the prefix keeps the end markers distinct.  You can then define the count, or for "sequential" enums starting with 0, use the marker value directly (e.g. "blah all_blahs[blah_end_marker];" - though I'm starting to think the const int blah_count makes more sense...

Comment: Only works if values assigned are monotonically increasing by 1

Comment: What is the values are assigned non-consecutive value? Not gonna fly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since enums can't change at run-time, the best thing you can do is:

```
enum blah {
    FIRST = 7,
    SECOND = 15,
    THIRD = 9,
    LAST = 12
};
#define blahcount 4 /* counted manually, keep these in sync */
```

But I find it difficult to envisage a situation where that information would come in handy. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes why would you want to do that!

Comment: I have a situation where I want to randomly assign enum values to an array. I need to know how many different values there are so I can get the right range.

Answer (score 3):

```
int enaumVals[] =
{
FIRST,
SECOND,
THIRD,
LAST
};

#define NUM_ENUMS sizeof(enaumVals) / sizeof ( int );
```

Comment: This seems to require repeating the entire enum in an array, purely to allow use of sizeof - looks like more effort to me than just #define COUNT 4

Comment: In C size computes at compilation time. C is not an interpreted language, this method is as efficient as using a fix definition and simplifies maintenance.

Comment: Except that it isn't. This will pollute the symbols of your program with an useless array of `NUM_ENUMS` int. Your program will take longer to start, will use more disk space and so on. The only way to avoid this is to declare and define this in an independent compilation unit, but then you don't have `NUM_ENUMS` available so that won't work. Later on, if you add a member to your enum list, you might forget to do so in the array and `NUM_ENUMS` will not match anymore

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

// M_CONC and M_CONC_ come from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804003/7067195
#define M_CONC(A, B) M_CONC_(A, B)
#define M_CONC_(A, B) A##B

#define enum_count_suffix _count
#define count(tag) M_CONC(tag, enum_count_suffix)
#define countable_enum(tag, ...) \
  enum tag {__VA_ARGS__}; \
  const size_t count(tag) = sizeof((int []) {__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int)

// The following declares an enum with tag `color` and 3 constants: `red`,
// `green`, and `blue`.
countable_enum(color, red, green, blue);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // The following prints 3, as expected.
  printf("number of elements in enum: %d\n", count(color));
}
```

Comment: this is good *otherwise* but the OP was specifically asking for counting the members when the values are explicitly valued and there your code would break.