# Creating a composite type from two enum classes, ready for STL map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, enums

I would like to create a composite type out of two `enum classes`.

```
enum class Color {RED, GREEN, BLUE};
enum class Shape {SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE};

class Object {
  Color color;
  Shape shape;
public:
};
```

In order to use `Object` in an STL container like `std::map<>` I would need to overload the less-than operator. However, in order to flatten both enum classes into one linear index I somehow need the number of elements (NoE) of the enum classes:

```
friend bool operator< (const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs) {
  return NoE(Shape)*lhs.color+lhs.shape < NoE(Shape)*rhs.color+rhs.shape;
}
```

How can this be done without entering the same information (number of elements) in two places in the program in a nice way? (Nice way means no `FIRST_ELEMENT, LAST_ELEMENT`, preprocessor magic, etc.)

Question ([Number of elements in an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712463/number-of-elements-in-an-enum)) is similar but does not address `enum classes`.

I would like to know what is the best way to implement this kind of composite types in C++11. Is the enum class definition strong enough, or is it necessary to say:?

```
enum class Color {RED=0, GREEN=1, BLUE=2};
enum class Shape {SQUARE=0, CIRCLE=1, TRIANGLE=2};
```

Comment: As far as I know the `enum` situation hasn't changed in C++11.

Comment: Why do you need to flatten?  That's not a requirement for `std::map`, which simply requires strict weak ordering.  You can easily do that with some nested comparisons.

Comment: `operator<` is only required if it is going to be the key in `map`, not if it is the value. Assuming it is the key, why not give `Color` or `Shape` precedence in the comparator? It is no less meaningful than the posted `operator<`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As commented and as already stated by others, give precedence to either `Shape` or `Color` in the `operator<` and only compare the other if the first is equal.
An alternative implementation for `operator<` using [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <tuple>
friend bool operator<(const Object& lhs, const Object& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.color, lhs.shape) < std::tie(rhs.color, rhs.shape);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider using simply `std::tuple<Color, Shape>` as the "composite enum."  This will come with comparison operators already defined for you, using a dictionary ordering. For example, valid code:

```
bool b = std::make_tuple(Color::RED, Shape::CIRCLE)
       < std::make_tuple(Color::GREEN, Shape::SQUARE);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a linear index, you can simply compare them lexicographically:

```
friend bool operator< (const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs) {
  if (lhs.color < rhs.color) return true;
  else if (lhs.color > rhs.color) return false;
  else return lhs.shape < rhs.shape;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question, but you don't actually *need* the number of `Color` to compare them :

```
friend bool operator< (const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs) {
    if(lhs.color > rhs.color) {
        return false;
    }
    if(lhs.color < rhs.color) { 
        return true;
    }
    return lhs.shape < rhs.shape;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to express is that to determine the order of your Objects, you first need to compare the color, and then check the shape in case the color was the same. Instead of linearizing that, if would simply use boolean operators.

```
friend bool operator< (const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs) 
{
   return ( (lhs.color < rhs.color) 
           || ( (lhs.color == rhs.color ) && ( lhs.shape < rhs.color) ) )
}
```

EDIT: Actually, you can also use an upper bound for the number of objects, the behaviour will be the same:

```
friend bool operator< (const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs) {
  return 10000*lhs.color+lhs.shape < 10000*rhs.color+rhs.shape;
}
```

but that introduces a "magic number" (so not such a good idea).

Answer (score 2):

You only need to compare `shape` if `color` is the same for both.

Using a ternary you can make it look nice too:

```
friend bool operator< (const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs) {
     return lhs.color == rhs.color ? (lhs.shape < rhs.shape)
                                   : (lhs.color < rhs.color);
}
```