# Comparison Operator for Structure key in C++ Map Table

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, operator-keyword

I have data that is uniquely identified by a combination of 3 integers.

For example:
Item #1: 10,20,1
Item #2: 10,21,0
Item #3: 0,14,13
Item #4: 103,324,78

My structure:

```
struct structureKeyID
{
    int keyA;
    int keyB;
    int keyC;

    // Comparison operator for table sorting.
    bool operator<(const structureKeyID& param) const
    {
        if (keyA < param.keyA) return true;
        if (keyB < param.keyB) return true;
        if (keyC < param.keyC) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

map <structureKeyID, classDataRecord> tableRecords;
```

I've found if I add a key (0,0,1):

```
structureKeyID keyID1;
keyID1.keyA = 0;
keyID1.keyB = 0;
keyID1.keyC = 1;
tableRecords[keyID1] = <data>;
```

I then check if key (0,1,0) exists:

```
structureKeyID keyID2;
keyID1.keyA = 0;
keyID1.keyB = 1;
keyID1.keyC = 0;
if (tableRecords.find(keyID2) != tableRecords.end())
```

Then I will get an error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   \include\xtree Line: 1268
>   Expression: invalid operator

Whereas, if I check if key (0,0,2) or if key (10,0,2) exists it works fine.

What is the proper way to build the comparison operator for this situation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340680/creating-a-composite-type-from-two-enum-classes-ready-for-stl-map/16341009#16341009 which uses `std::tie`. If you do not have c++11 then `boost::tie` is available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
// Comparison operator for table sorting.
bool operator<(const structureKeyID& param) const
{
    if (keyA < param.keyA) return true;
    if (keyA > param.keyA) return false;
    if (keyB < param.keyB) return true;
    if (keyB > param.keyB) return false;
    if (keyC < param.keyC) return true;
    if (keyC > param.keyC) return false;
    return false;
}
```

Your version doesn't define a consistent ordering (the technical term is a strict weak ordering) because with your comparison function it would be possible to have A < B < C < A, so `std::map` gets confused.

Comment: That makes sense! 3 lines of code and it's working great, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The easiest implementation of a less-than comparison satisfying strict weak ordering is with `std::tie`, available in the `<tuple>` header:

```
bool operator<(const structureKeyID& param) const
{
  return std::tie(keyA, keyB, keyC) < std::tie(param.keyA, param.keyB, param.keyC);
}
```

This performs a lexicographical comparison. If you don't have C++11 support, you can find equivalents in TR1 and Boost.

Comment: I don't have tuple available to me in this project. I appreciate the info though and will look into ties in the future. Thanks!

Comment: If the keyA, keyB, etc were floats, how does this effect the stability of using such a structure as a key in a map? While using a single float as a map key is prone to error, is this combination of floats using `std::tie` any better?