# Enum mapping robust to refactoring

Tags: c++, enums, c++14

I want to map values of a (scoped) enum to some other values. For instance, here I map `Color` to other enum `Group`:

```
enum class Color {
  Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, White, Black, 
  COUNT  // Needed to know the number of items
};
enum class Group {
  Primary, Secondary, Neutral
};

Group GetGroupOfColor(Color color);  // Mapping function I'm going to implement
```

I want to make sure that **if anyone changes the number of elements in `Color` enum, this function will fail to compile.**

I came up with the only solution to this problem:

```
Group GetGroupOfColor(Color color)
{
  static const Group color2group[] = {
    Group::Primary,    // Red
    Group::Primary,    // Green
    Group::Primary,    // Blue
    Group::Secondary,  // Cyan
    Group::Secondary,  // Magenta
    Group::Secondary,  // Yellow
    Group::Neutral,    // White
    Group::Neutral     // Black
  };
  static_assert(ARRAY_SIZE(color2group) == size_t(Color::COUNT), "DEADBEEF!");

  auto index = size_t(color);
  assert(index < size_t(Color::COUNT));
  return color2group[index];
}
```

where `ARRAY_SIZE` may be implemented like the following:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t ARRAY_SIZE(T(&)[N])
{
  return N;
}
```

This implementation does what I want, but it has a bunch of drawbacks:

- Adds this ugly `COUNT` item in `Color` enum (bothers me most)
- Will fail silently if someone reorders items of `Color`
- Not applicable for not-continuous enums, i.e. with explicitly assigned values (this one is not really important)

My question is, **is there a way to improve this implementation?** Maybe some different approach I did not even think about. Maybe with its own drawbacks, which I will find less annoying.

See also:

- [Number of elements in an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712463/number-of-elements-in-an-enum)
- [Compile time sizeof_array without using a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500363/compile-time-sizeof-array-without-using-a-macro)

Comment: The whole point of enums is that they are supposed to be totally separate types. Your best approach is to code the conversion explicitly with a switch statement - but you will have to ensure that both enums are kept in synch and the conversion code is changed when one of the enums is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a `switch` statement.

```
switch (colour) {
    case Colour::Red:   return Group::Primary;
    //...
    case Colour::Black: return Group::Neutral;
}
return Group::Invalid;  // or throw, assert, or whatever.
```

That should cover all your needs:

> Adds this ugly `COUNT` item in `Color enum` (bothers me most)

No need for that, just a `case` for each enumerator.

> Will fail silently if someone reorders items of `Color`

Each `case` is explicitly named, so the value of each enumerator doesn't matter (as long as they're unique; but you'll get an error if that's not the case).

> Not applicable for not-continuous enums

Again, named `case` statements don't care about the actual values.

> if anyone changes the number of elements in `Color enum`, this function will fail to compile

While not guaranteed, most compilers should be able to warn if there are unhandled enumerators in a switch (as long as there's no `default` branch). For GCC, the option is `-Wswitch` (included in `-Wall`), along with `-Werror` if you want it to cause failure.

Comment: Very nice thought about compiler warning!

Answer (score 1):

How about a slightly different approach - create a kind of enriched enum :

```
class Color {
  public :
    enum class Name { RED, GREEN, BLUE, CYAN, MAGENTA, YELLOW, WHITE, BLACK };
    enum class Group { PRIMARY, SECONDARY, NEUTRAL };

    uint32_t rgb;
    Name name;
    Group group;

    static const Color Red;
    static const Color Green;
    static const Color Blue;
    static const Color Cyan;
    static const Color Magenta;
    static const Color Yellow;
    static const Color White;
    static const Color Black;

  private :
    Color(uint32_t rgb, Name name, Group group) : rgb(rgb), name(name), group(group) { }

  public :
    inline operator const Name() const { return name; }
};

const Color Color::Red     = Color(0xFF0000, Color::Name::RED,     Color::Group::PRIMARY);
const Color Color::Green   = Color(0x00FF00, Color::Name::GREEN,   Color::Group::PRIMARY);
const Color Color::Blue    = Color(0x0000FF, Color::Name::BLUE,    Color::Group::PRIMARY);
const Color Color::Cyan    = Color(0x00FFFF, Color::Name::CYAN,    Color::Group::SECONDARY);
const Color Color::Magenta = Color(0xFF00FF, Color::Name::MAGENTA, Color::Group::SECONDARY);
const Color Color::Yellow  = Color(0xFFFF00, Color::Name::YELLOW,  Color::Group::SECONDARY);
const Color Color::White   = Color(0xFFFFFF, Color::Name::WHITE,   Color::Group::NEUTRAL);
const Color Color::Black   = Color(0x000000, Color::Name::BLACK,   Color::Group::NEUTRAL);
```

which can then be used like this :

```
void fun(const Color& color) {
    switch (color) {
        case Color::Name::RED   : std::cout << "red"; break;
        case Color::Name::GREEN : std::cout << "green"; break;
        case Color::Name::BLUE  : std::cout << "blue"; break;
        // etc.
    }
    std::cout << " ";
    switch (color.group) {
        case Color::Group::PRIMARY   : std::cout << "primary"; break;
        case Color::Group::SECONDARY : std::cout << "secondary"; break;
        case Color::Group::NEUTRAL   : std::cout << "neutral"; break;
    }
    std::cout << " : " << std::hex << color.rgb << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Applicability heavily depends on use cases. Need to think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'd like to detect changes to the `Color` enum because you want to ensure that every color can always be mapped to some group? If so, you could establish the mapping using some macros which make it impossible to add a new `Color` value without also defining what it maps to. Something like:

```
#define COLORMAP \
  MAP_COLOR(Red, Primary) \
  MAP_COLOR(Green, Primary) \
  MAP_COLOR(Blue, Primary) \
  MAP_COLOR(Cyan, Secondary) \
  MAP_COLOR(Magenta, Secondary) \
  MAP_COLOR(Yellow, Secondary) \
  MAP_COLOR(White, Neutral) \
  MAP_COLOR(Black, Neutral)
```

Defining the `MAP_COLOR` appropriately will then allow you to define the `Color` enum as well as the mapping function from a single source:

```
#define MAP_COLOR(a, b) a,
enum class Color {
  COLORMAP
  Invalid
};
#undef MAP_COLOR

enum class Group {
  Primary, Secondary, Neutral, Invalid
};

#define MAP_COLOR(a, b) case Color::a: return Group::b;
Group GetGroupOfColor(Color color)
{
  switch (color) {
    COLORMAP
    case Color::Invalid: return Group::Invalid;
  }
  return Group::Invalid;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is called "X Macro" technique. It is interesting, but very obscure. It also couples definition of `Color` items with `Group` items. What if I want to map colors on other entities, or even get rid of `Group` at all?

Comment: @Mikhail: If you want to map colors to other values you'd extend the `MAP_COLOR` macro to take three (or even more) arguments.

Comment: @Mikhail: By the way, thanks for mentioning the term "X macro", I didn't even know this technique had a name!

Comment: Glad you learned something new :) I heard it a couple of days ago for myself, from my team lead, when discussing the same problem with him.