# How to define size of enum minus one element

Tags: c, enums

if I have enum:

```
typedef enum
{
   A= 0,
   B= 1,
   C =2,
   D= 4,
   E= 6,
   F= 8,
   G= 10,

   MAX_ELEMENTS
}my_enum
```

How can I declare the number of elements within  *enum* without one element?

something like this:

```
uint8 enum_numb_elements = MAX_ELEMENTS - 1
```

This is not a good practice to do arithmetic operation on *enums*. Is there an other way?

Comment: What does `enum_size` mean? `sizeof` would give a very different answer from `MAX_ELEMENTS - 1`.

Comment: @n.m. I mean the number of elements in enum

Comment: The number of elements in an enum is different from the largest value in the enum. Do you need the number of discrete things the enum can represent or the largest value in the enum?

Comment: @n.m. Yes, exactly the number of discrete things in enum.

Comment: Have you checked [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/712487/1620779) answer?

Comment: Neither gives the number of elements in your enum. The only way to get this number is to count the elements by hand.

Comment: @sjsam That won't work with the sparse enum like this question has.

Comment: @user694733 of course it won't as the other commenter has already mentioned..

Comment: @kingkong I think you would be better off defining the wider problem you are trying to solve and why your enums have gaps etc.  There may be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: In C a variable of an enumerated  type can hold any value of some integral type (char or int or unsigned int...) . The exact type depends on the enum itself and the implementation but in any case the number of different values is at least 127.

Answer (score 4):

You can define it, sort of, but it involves some boiler-plate that isn't all too pleasant, and pollutes the global/tag namespace a lot/bit.

If you leverage the notorious [X macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros) for the job, it would look like this:

```
#define LIST_OF_ENUM_IDS \
    X(A, 0) \
    X(B, 1) \
    X(C, 2) \
    X(D, 4) \
    X(E, 6) \
    X(F, 8) \
    X(G, 10)

#define X(id, val) \
  id = val,

typedef enum
{
  LIST_OF_ENUM_IDS
} my_enum;

#undef X

#define X(id, val) id##_impl_helper,

enum my_enum_impl_helper__ {
  LIST_OF_ENUM_IDS
  MY_ENUM_MAX_ELEMENTS
};

#undef X
```

Live example: [On Ideone](http://ideone.com/8iFjCe)

---

Alternatively, some shops will instead rely on bold comments and code reviews to catch such things:

```
/********************************************
*
**
*** ATTENTION! Remember to bump MAX_ELEMENTS
*** should you add new values to the enum
**
*
********************************************/
typedef enum
{
   A= 0,
   B= 1,
   C =2,
   D= 4,
   E= 6,
   F= 8,
   G= 10,

   MAX_ELEMENTS = 7 /// Bump this if you add new values!
}my_enum;
```

Which *can* work not all too bad, despite the human factor.

Comment: `my_enum_impl_helper__` tag is not necessary, and could be left out to reduce namespace pollution a bit.

Comment: @user694733 - Very true. But I already pollute the global namespace quite a lot with the enums themselves. Might as well leave the tag to know what it all ties into (many IDE's can display the enclosing tag, and `my_enum_impl_helper__ ` is more descriptive than "anonymous enum 394").

Comment: Your second solution is more simpler one and urges to use common sense.

Comment: @sjsam - I find that seeing the ugly first, helps coax people towards the saner solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep enums contiguous to exploit the 'features' of C..

```
typedef enum
{
   A,
   B,
   C,
   D,
   E,
   F,
   G,
   MAX_ELEMENTS
} my_enum;

int element_array[MAX_ELEMENTS] =
{
    0,
    1,
    2,
    4,
    6,
    8,
    10
};
```

Given this construct, NUM_ELEMENTS adjusts automatically if you add/subtract enums, and you can use my_elem in for loops, etc.  The major issue of concern is that you need to remember to maintain element_array in conjunction with my_enum when you add or remove enums.

A for loop example

```
my_elem elem;
for (elem = (my_elem)0; elem < MAX_ELEMENTS; elem++)
{
    printf("The value of element %d is %d\n", elem, element_array[elem] );
}
```