# for loop with enum in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, enums, pascal

I have problem trying to make for each loop in C++. I'm not certain is this is possible in C++ if it is I still dont know to make it.

I have one simple problem written in pascal that does finding of the day in year when it is a friday 13 or saturday 25 no metter which day.

In pascal I have code like this:

```
{First I declare types}
type
    months = (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December);
...
{Then I declare variable for months}
var
    m: mesec;
...
{Then I can declare for loop that will loop over months}
for m:= januar to december do
...
```

The similar way of doing a for each loop over enumerations is possible in python too.
My question is:

Is there any way of doing for or even while loop over enumerations in C++?

I know this may seem as a beginers question but I tried on few different ways to do it doesnt work. Doesnt compile.

Comment: You can cast to int. It's not good practice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/c-iterate-through-an-enum

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479746/loop-on-enumeration-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this directly in C++. There are a few workarounds, though.

- If the values of the enum are increased by 1 (i.e. have consecutive values, as they do by default, in case you don't explicitly set their values), you can use them as normal `int`s, and increase the cycle variable by 1 each time until it equals the last `enum`'s value. This is described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261963/c-iterate-through-an-enum).
- If the values are *not* increasing by 1 (e.g. `enum E {FIRST = 5, SECOND = 10}`, it becomes more tricky. You could make an array holding all possible values and use it (that's a crappy solution, but it works):

  ```
  enum E
  {
      FIVE = 5,
      TEN = 10,
      THREE = 3
  };
  E arr[3] = {FIVE,TEN,THREE};
  E iterator;
  for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
      iterator = arr[i];
      //do something with it
  }
  ```

Comment: One benefit of this solution is the conciseness of ranged for: `for(  E val : arr )`. Depending on your use case, you might benefit from having multiple subsets/orderings of the enum: `E oddValues[] = { THREE, FIVE }; for( E val : oddValues ) ...`

Answer (score 6):

You could do following in c++ provided the enum values are consecutive

```
enum Months
  {
  January,
  February,
  // etc...
  December,
  Last
  };

for (int month = January; month != Last; ++month)
  {
  // do stuff
  }
```

Comment: But only if enums have consecutive values.

Comment: This stops right before `December` which is incorrect. Generally another enum value is added last called `NumMonths` and you use that.

Comment: Yes enum values are consecutive