# What prevents C++ from being a strict superset of C?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“C subset of C++” -> Where not ? examples ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/c-subset-of-c-where-not-examples)

I'm aware that C++ is not a strict superset of C. What language features prevent C++ from being a superset of C?

Comment: This question has been answered a 1000 times, I'd like to see a technical answer that demonstrates it's simply not possible, keywords and C99 aside...

Comment: @Matt Joiner: why put C99 aside?

Comment: @Matt: demonstrate that *what* isn’t possible? Of course every C program can be refactored to valid C++. That is rather trivial, given that both languages are Turing complete.

Comment: @Konrad: It's nearly that trivial, but not quite. C is Turing complete and also provides access to a filesystem. Its computing model has outputs that are not the same as the outputs of Turing's model. A hypothetical language which was Turing complete but did not provide access to a filesystem, would not be a superset of C in the "can be refactored" sense. But because C++ provides access to all C's libraries and to `volatile` memory, we're looking good on the I/O score.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The elephant in the room: the following is valid C but not valid C++.

```
int typename = 1;
```

Substitute your favorite C++ reserved word.

Comment: The shortest example would be `int new = 1;`

Answer (score 25):

C++ also does not support variable-length arrays, where:

```
int array[n];
```

is valid in C, but not C++. A C++ version of the above would be:

```
int *array = new int[n];
  ...
delete [] array;
```

Comment: You might want to clarify that `n` is a variable, not a constant, otherwise it would indeed be valid in C++.

Comment: I would replace `new int[]` and `delete[]` with `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Can you explain why it is that you can do the first in C? Would `array` be allocated on the stack somehow, and what if `n` were too large for that? I don't know C well at all, and I'm curious what exactly is going on there.

Comment: variable length arrays were added in C99.

Comment: @notJim: yes, `array` would be allocated on the stack. If `n` were too large for that then if you're lucky the implementation terminates due to a signal (or other OS-driven sanction). If you're unlucky, the implementation blindly carries on trashing someone else's memory. Depends on the the OS/compiler.

Comment: That is **NOT** how you would do it in C++.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yup, that's idiomatic C++.

Comment: g++ allows this. Very hacky, and used it in college

Comment: I would do it like `int *array = alloca(n*sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 14):

There is a special [wiki](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B) entry that summarizes a lot of issues.

Answer (score 9):

Simple example, consider this declaration:

```
int f();
```

This is valid C, but invalid C++: `f(3, 2, -5, "wtf");`

Explanation: in C, `int f()` is treated like `int f(...)` (at least at the first call site). Declare as `int f(void)` if you don't want `f` to take parameters.

Comment: No, `int f()` is not really `int f(...)` , there's a big semantic difference. In the first case, this means I don't know the parameters of that function and at the first encounter of the function call, the default types used as parameters declares the signature of that function, subsequent calls must adhere to that implicit prototype and the compiler should warn if you call the function with other params. With the ellipse it's not the case, each call can have different parameters without warning.

Comment: @tristopia: Whatever it is, it's really a *don't do this* thing.

Comment: Absolutely, I was just nitpicking as there is a real but subtle difference. This said I haven't downvoted your contribution as the message is mainly ok.

Answer (score 3):

One from top of my head - C++ does not support default int.

Comment: Implicit return type is not allowed in C either, except before C99.