# Does the working of sizeof operator different in c andd c++

Tags: c++, c

I have written a small printf statement which is working different in C and C++:

```
    int i;
    printf ("%d %d %d %d %d \n", sizeof(i), sizeof('A'), sizeof(sizeof('A')),    sizeof(float), sizeof(3.14));
```

The output for the above program in c using gcc compiler is   4 4 8 4 8

The output for the above program in c++ using g++ compiler is 4 1 8 4 8

I expected 4 1 4 4 8 in c. But the result is not so.

The third parameter in the printf  sizeof(sizeof('A')) is giving 8

Can anyone give me the reasoning for this

Comment: vs2012: ``4 1 4 4 8``.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the `sizeof` operator in particular; rather, the size of character literals in C is different than C++, because character literals in C are of type `int`, whereas in C++ they are of type `char`.

See [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why does sizeof (3.14) takes 8 bytes. 3.14 is float right.

Comment: No, it's a double.  3.14f is a float.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is implementation specific. `sizeof()` returns `size_t` which is unsigned integer. Its size is dependent on machine(32-bit vs 64-bit) and also implementation.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c) :

In C, `char` is one byte, but `'a'` is an `int` constant so it is (in your case, depending on what architecture you compile on!) four bytes wide.
in C++, both `char` and `'a'` are `char` with one byte size.

The most important message is that **C++ is not a superset of C. It has a lot of small breaking changes like this.**

Comment: `int` doesn't have to be four bytes.

Comment: Thank You I asked the question based on the last quote mentioned by you. C++ is superset of C

Comment: @Kranthi It most certainly is not a strict superset. Related: ["C subset of C++" -> Where not ? examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1201593), [What prevents C++ from being a strict superset of C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3777031)

Comment: Why does sizeof (3.14) takes 8 bytes. 3.14 is float right

Comment: @Kranthi Kumar In Java, C and C++, `3.14` and `3d` are a double literal while `3.14f` is a float literal