# Large C macros. What's the benefit?

Tags: c, macros

I've been working with a large codebase written primarily by programmers who no longer work at the company.  One of the programmers apparently had a special place in his heart for *very* long macros.  The only benefit I can see to using macros is being able to write functions that don't need to be passed in all their parameters (which is recommended against in a best practices guide I've read).  Other than that I see no benefit over an inline function.

Some of the macros are so complicated I have a hard time imagining someone even writing them.  I tried creating one in that spirit and it was a nightmare.  Debugging is extremely difficult, as it takes N+ lines of code into 1 in the a debugger (e.g. there was a segfault somewhere in this large block of code.  Good luck!).  I had to actually pull the macro out and run it un-macro-tized to debug it.  The only way I could see the person having written these is by automatically generating them out of code written in a function after he had debugged it (or by being smarter than me and writing it perfectly the first time, which is always possible I guess).

Am I missing something?  Am I crazy?  Are there debugging tricks I'm not aware of? Please fill me in.  I would really like to hear from the macro-lovers in the audience. :)

Answer (score 8):

To me the best use of macros is to compress code and reduce errors. The downside is obviously in debugging, so they have to be used with care.

I tend to think that if the resulting code isn't an order of magnitude smaller and less prone to errors (meaning the macros take care of some bookkeeping details) then it wasn't worth it.

In C++, many uses like this can be replaced with templates, but not all.  A simple example of Macros that are useful are in the event handler macros of MFC -- without them, creating event tables would be much harder to get right and the code you'd have to write (and read) would be much more complex.

Comment: I can understand some short macros for those reasons, but is there any benefit to having a sanity validation function be declared as a macro vs an inline function?  I run into lots of failures inside some X_VALIDATE macros at work, but they comprise multiple assert statements and loops.  A core file won't tell me which assert failed (thus making debugging harder).  It seems to me this could be an inline function with no cost and lots of benefits.  Would you agree?

Comment: Main benefit to assert in a macro (rather than inline) is that __FILE__ and __LINE__ will be correct.  Since you have a core, you can get the whole stack, so not a big deal for you.  If it can be written without a macro, do it without a macro.  If it can only be done with a macro and you get a benefit, then do it.  For me, the benefit needs to be much simpler code or much less error prone code.

Comment: __FILE__ and __LINE__ are meant to be `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` above (didn't know I needed to escape)

Comment: One of my favorite tricks is to use a macro to be given file and line numbers as parameters to a function, then macro-tize the call to that function ie _mycall(int p1, int p2, char* filename, int lineno) #define mycall(p1, p2) _mycall(p1, p2, \_\_FILE\_\_, \_\_LINE\_\_

Comment: It seems to have ruined my ability to post that correctly.  The first "mycall" should have been prefixed with an underscore and apparently I don't know how to escape them :)

Answer (score 4):

If the macros are extremely long, they probably make the code short but efficient. In effect, he might have used macros to explicitly inline code or remove decision points from the run-time code path.

It might be important to understand that, in the past, such optimizations weren't done by many compilers, and some things that we take for granted today, like fast function calls, weren't valid then.

Answer (score 3):

To me, macros are evil. With their so many side effects, and the fact that in C++ you can gain same perf gains with inline, they are not worth the risk.

For ex. see this short macro:

```
#define max(a, b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

then try this call:

```
max(i++, j++)
```

More. Say you have

```
#define PLANETS 8
#define SOCCER_MIDDLE_RIGHT 8
```

if an error is thrown, it will refer to '8', but not either of its meaninful representations.

Comment: Those aren't a good use of macros, as you point out.  There are reasons to use them -- I don't believe in evil features, just features used evilly :) -- used correctly, macros are very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I only know of two reasons for doing what you describe.

First is to force functions to be inlined.  This is pretty much pointless, since the inline keyword usually does the same thing, and function inlining is often a premature micro-optimization anyway.

Second is to simulate nested functions in C or C++.  This is related to your "writing functions that don't need to be passed in all their parameters" but can actually be quite a bit more powerful than that.  [Walter Bright gives](http://www.ddj.com/architect/184401792) examples of where nested functions can be useful.

There are other reasons to use of macros, such as using preprocessor-specific functionality (like including `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in autogenerated error messages) or reducing boilerplate code in ways that functions and templates can't (the [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library excels here; see [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) or [this sample enum code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217549/which-typesafe-enum-in-c-are-you-using/439004#439004) for examples), but these reasons don't seem to apply for doing what you describe.

Comment: The inline keyword does not force functions to be inlined, although you're right that often it's a mistake for the programmer to be trying to make those decisions.

Answer (score 2):

Very long macros will have performance drawbacks, like increased compiled binary size, and there are certainly other reasons for not using them.

For the most problematic macros, I would consider running the code through the preprocessor, and replacing the macro output with function calls (inline if possible) or straight LOC. If the macros exists for compatibility with other architectures/OS's, you might be stuck though.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the benefit is code replication without the eventual maintenance cost - that is, instead of copying code elsewhere you create a macro from it and only have to edit it once...

Of course, you could also just make a method to be called but that is sort of more work... I'm against much macro use myself, just trying to present a potential rationale.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of good reasons to write macros in C.

Some of the most important are for creating configuration tables using x-macros, for making function like macros that can accept multiple parameter types as inputs and converting tables from human readable/configurable/understandable values into computer used values.

I cant really see a reason for people to write very long macros, except for the historic automatic function inline.

I would say that when debugging *complex macros*, (when writing **X** macros etc) I tend to preprocess the source file and substitute the preprocessed file for the original.

This allows you to see the C code generated, and gives you real lines to work with in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use macros at all.  Inline functions serve every useful purpose a macro can do.  Macro allow you to do very weird and counterintuitive things like splitting up identifiers (How does someone search for the identifier then?).

Answer (score 0):

I have also worked on a product where a legacy programmer (who thankfully is long gone) also had a special love affair with Macros. His 'custom' scripting language is the height of sloppiness. This was compounded by the fact that he wrote his C++ classes in C, meaning all class functions and variables were all public. Anyways, he wrote almost everything in macro's and variadic functions (Another hideous monstrosity foisted on the world). So instead of writing a proper template class he would use a Macro instead! He also resorted to macro's to create factory classes as well, instead of normal code... His code is pretty much unmaintanable.

From what I have seen, macro's can be used when they are small and are used declaratively and don't contain moving parts like loops, and other program flow expressions. It's OK if the macro is one or at the most two lines long and it declares and instance of something. Something that won't break during runtime. Also macro's should not contain class definitions, or function definitions. If the macro contains code that needs to be stepped into using a debugger than the macro should be removed and replace with something else.

They can also be useful for wrapping custom tracing/debugging functionality. For instance you want custom tracing in debug builds but not release builds.

Anyways when you are working in legacy code like that, just be sure to remove a bit of the macro mess a bit at a time. If you keep it up, with enough time eventually you will remove them all and make life a bit easier for yourself. I have done this in the past, with especially messy macro's. What I do is turn on the compiler switch to have the preprocessor generate an output file. Then I raid that file, and copy the code, re-indent it, and replace the macro with the generated code. Thank goodness for that compiler feature.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the legacy code I've worked with used macros very extensively in the place of methods. The reasoning was that the computer/OS/runtime had an extremely small stack, so that stack overflows were a common problem. Using macros instead of methods meant that there were fewer methods on the stack.

Luckily, most of that code was obsolete, so it is (mostly) gone now.

Comment: I guess the compilers back then weren't so good at inlining. Today, inline functions should solve this.

Comment: @ugoren Yes, this definitely is not needed anymore. On the other hand, I also couldn't just simply change the macros into methods, since the macros often used variables declared in "outer" macros or in the method using them... *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

C89 did not have inline functions. If using a compiler with extensions disabled (which is a desirable thing to do for several reasons), then the macro might be the only option.

Although C99 came out in 1999, there was resistance to it for a long time; commercial compiler vendors didn't feel it was worth their time to implement C99. Some (e.g. MS) still haven't. So for many companies it was not a viable practical decision to use C99 conforming mode, even up to today in the case of some compilers.

I have used C89 compilers that did have an extension for inline functions, but the extension was buggy (e.g. multiple definition errors when there should not be), things like that may dissuade a programmer from using inline functions.

Another thing is that the macro version effectively forces that the function will actually be inlined. The C99 `inline` keyword is only a compiler hint and the compiler may still decide to generate a single instance of the function code which is linked like a non-inline function. (One compiler that I still use will do this if the function is not trivial and returning `void`).