# Strongly typed `enum`s in VS10?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [forward/strong enum in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603314/forward-strong-enum-in-vs2010)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934183/) pointed to a wiki page for [C++0x support](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) which lists **Strongly typed `enum`s** as *Partially supported* in VS10.

However the following is a compilation error:

```
enum class boolean { no, yes, maybe };
```

Any idea what constitutes partial support when the basic syntax isn't accepted?

---

Compilation error message:

> error C2332: 'enum' : missing tag name
>     error C2236: unexpected 'class' 'boolean'. Did you forget a ';'?

Comment: Posting the compilation error would help.

Comment: @George Yeah, and it turns out that the "partial" support is in C++/CLI only.