# Boost Enum 256 Element Limit

Tags: c++, boost, enums, limit

I'm using the enum v4.6 library from the [Boost Vault](https://github.com/boost-vault/Miscellaneous) (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217549/which-typesafe-enum-in-c-are-you-using) [stackoverflow.com]), but have come across an element limit of 256 (that is, the max number of elements per enum = 256).

I understand this has something to do with the boost preprocessor library and some investigation led me to `boost/preprocessor/config/limits.hpp`, but changing these values had no effect since they are purely "informational" ([link](https://groups.google.com/group/boost-list/browse_thread/thread/b043c23a8170a59) [groups.google.com])

Is there any way of increasing this limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to increase the upper limit of elements/arguments you can use with the Boost preprocessor library. Therefore, since the enum library depends on Boost.PP you seem to be out of luck.