# Collecting a list of functions that later should be called in macros

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I am writing a small library with which enums in C++ should get easier. The syntax is something like:

```
ENUM_START(MyEnum)
    ENUM_VAL(Val1)
    ENUM_VAL(Val2)
    ...
ENUM_END
```

This macros create a class MyEnum with allows for example the following access:

```
MyEnum bla=MyEnum::Val1;
for(MyEnum::iterator iter=MyEnum::begin();iter!=MyEnum::end();++iter)
    cout << iter->toString();
```

and a few more features like storing additional data (for example strings) to enum values.

The macros are finished and work, but are not as easy to define as shown above. For this I need a way to create a list of initializer functions with the ENUM_VAL macros that I later can call. Something like the following boost::mpl approach:

```
typedef mpl::vector<> list__COUNTER__;
#define ENUM_VAL(Name)                                                         \
    ...                                                                        \
    struct Init##Name{void init() {initialization code}};                      \
    typedef mpl::push_back<                                                    \
        list##(__COUNTER-1),                                                   \
        Init##Name                                                             \
      >::type list##__COUNTER__;                                               \
```

This way list##(__COUNTER__-1) contains in the end the type Init##Name and I can in the end call init() on all stored types using mpl foreach.

The problem now is the naming. I have to use __COUNTER__ twice per macro instantiation, which increments the counter twice. I already searched and found out that

- The C preprocessor doesn't calculate (__COUNTER__-1) when naming the variables
- there is no way to read __COUNTER__ without incrementing it.

So I need another way to collect a list of functions I later can call.

Comment: One downside of this approach is that the debugger probably won't display the "enum" names when viewing variables of type `MyEnum`, unlike with real enums.

Comment: You can probably get the behavior you want using 'X macro' techniques: http://drdobbs.com/184401387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor) and specifically it's [sequences](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/data/sequences.html). This would result in a macro-usage similar to this:

```
MAKE_ENUM(MyEnum, (Val1)(Val2)(Val3))
```

Using `SEQ_ENUM`, `SEQ_FOR_EACH_I` et al, you can then generate the code relatively easy.

There was also a proposed [Boost.Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439004/168225) which might suit your needs already.

Comment: Sequences are very powerful.  I can't say I'm tempted to use macros very often, but they are usually why.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from template meta-programming, there is just template engines that could run as a script before your preprocessor ever saw the code.  **This has the added benefit that its just plain code, so you can debug it easier**.

The downside is adding another tool requirement if someone wants to change something.

I have used [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) for this before and I was not disappointed with the result.