# C/C++ enum and char * array

Tags: c++, c, enums, char

Ran accross the following code in an article and didn't think it was standard C/C++ syntax for the char* array.  As a test, both Visual C++ (visual studio 2005) and C++ Builder Rad XE both reject the 2nd line.

Without using `#define`s, anyone have any tricks/tips for keeping `enum`s and a string array sort of in sync without resorting to STL ?

More of a curiosity question.

```
enum TCOLOR { RED, GREEN, BLUE };

char *TNCOLOR[] = { [RED]="Red", [GREEN]="Green", [BLUE]="Blue" };
```

as an aside, the article this came from is quite old and I believe this might work under GCC but have not tested.

Comment: 2 reasons:  1.  STL causes code bloat and 2. I work on embedded systems where STL is generally not available.  A lot of my code files are pure C (not C++) which must compile on embedded platforms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are C99 designated initializers. GCC supports them in C90 mode (and in C++) as an extension. Read about it here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits

There is no good way to keep enums und strings in sync. If I'd really need this, then I'd write a script to grab the enums declarations from the source code and generate the strings arrays from that. I really hate doing this with macros.

UPDATE: Here's a question from last year which discusses enum->string conversion (for printing in this case)

[C++: Print out enum value as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342726/c-print-out-enum-value-as-text/3342815)

Comment: +1 for scripting... though I would probably script with macros :)

Answer (score 4):

```
char *TNCOLOR[] = { [RED]="Red", [GREEN]="Green", [BLUE]="Blue" };
```

This is allowed **only** in C99, **not** in C++03, C++0x,  or any other version of C.

Read about [Designated initializers for aggregate types - C99](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/designators.htm).

Answer (score 1):

This is C99 syntax, what is supported by GCC. With your requirements

- no #define
- no STL

you will probably not find a sync.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but this might help anyone else looking for a simple way to keep multiple arrays/enums in sync.

In my case, I simply wanted a compile-time check to determine whether my lists were out of sync, and since the sizeof operator is not evaluated until **after** the preprocessor does it's thing, this was the simplest way to do that.

In a header file of some sort...

```
enum ColorType
{
    Red=0,
    Blue,
    Green,
    ColorType_Max
};
```

In the same header or some other file perhaps...

```
char const* ColorTypeNames[]=
{
    "Red",
    "Blue",
    "Green"
};
```

In a cpp file somewhere...

```
const int s_ColorTypeCount = (int)ColorType_Max;
const int s_ColorNameCount = (int)(sizeof(ColorTypeNames)/sizeof(char const*));
const int s_ColorErrorA = 1/(s_ColorTypeCount/s_ColorNameCount);
const int s_ColorErrorB = 1/(s_ColorNameCount/s_ColorTypeCount);
```

Only when the two sizes match, will s_ColorErrorA and s_ColorErrorB equal 1.  Since the variables are constants, this will generate a compile-time divide by zero error when the two count variables differ.