# C++ Trickery : output actual enum, not its value

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Print out enum value as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342726/c-print-out-enum-value-as-text)

Say I have an enumeration:

```
typedef enum MyEnum_
{
  MY_ENUM_BLUE,
  MY_ENUM_RED,
  MY_ENUM_GREEN
} MyEnum;
```

And that I have a method that gets an "MyEnum" as parameter. I'd like write to log file the value of that MyEnum, but I don't want 0, 1 or 2 to appear there--- I'd like to output the actual enumeration string "MY_ENUM_xxxx", of course **without a switch/case block**..... and dealing with each value individually.

Is there some trickery or pattern, in c++ or using macros that would help me achieve that?

Comment: I believe these are compiler constants and not compiled into the code, unlike Java and C# which have metadata for types.

Comment: I know, that's why I also asked if there's a trick macro approach around this, that would alleviate the need for a lengthy switch/case block for each case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to typedef in c++

```
enum MyEnum_
{
  MY_ENUM_BLUE,
  MY_ENUM_RED,
  MY_ENUM_GREEN
} MyEnum;

#define TOSTR(x) #x

const char *names[]={TOSTR(MY_ENUM_BLUE),
               TOSTR(MY_ENUM_RED),
               TOSTR(MY_ENUM_GREEN)};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   MyEnum_ e=MY_ENUM_RED;

   std::cout << names[e] << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `enum ... {} MyEnum;` declare a global object named `MyEnum`?  Isn't it simpler to write `enum MyEnum {};`?

Comment: Note that this situation is delicate if values are assigned manually and not sequentially generated by the compiler.

Comment: @AndréCaron - very true - I just c&p the OP's code