# Loop through a vector, check output with enum and print enum name

Tags: c++, function, enums

I have the following function that loops through a vector and get the output of a public member functions. This output is a constant like 1, 8 or 3 etc.

```
void testItems(const TestObjectList* const testObject) {

              std::vector<ObjectTestFirst> testobjects = testObject->getTestObjects();             
              std::vector<ObjectTestFirst>::iterator itr;
              std::stringstream strbuffer;

              for (itr = testobjects.begin(); itr != testobjects.end(); itr++){
                     strbuffer << tc.toString(itr->getTimest()) << ",\t"
                            << itr->getObjectTest1() << ",\t"
                            << itr->getObjectTest2() << ",\t"
                            << itr->getObjectTest3() << ",\t"
                            << std::endl;
              }
              outfile << strbuffer.str() << std::endl;
}
```

I have a definition of these constants in a header file that I import (hpp) represented as a `enum`:

```
enum TestObjectClass {
    TestObjectClass_Zero = 0,
    TestObjectClass_TestApple = 1,
    TestObjectClass_TestOrange = 8,
    TestObjectClass_TestBanana = 3,
};
```

In the first code snippet that I show, the `testItems` function, how do I check the output of the public member function with the `enum` and print the `enum` name?

**Example:** `itr->getObjectTest1() << ",\t"` outputs 8 - I then check the enum and it match TestObjectClass_TestOrange = 8 so I print out TestObjectClass_TestOrange instead of the constant (8).

Comment: Easiest thing to do is to map your `enum` values to strings, you can't directly print your `enum`'s member names.

Comment: Please clarify: It looks like you're trying to get an enum name from it's value? If so, everything about for loops and test objects is irrelevant fluff.

Comment: Is this what you're asking: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11714325/224704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately since there is no generic enum-to-string function in C++11 (maybe C++17 will address this finally?) you have to roll your own.

```
enum class TestObjectClass : uint16_t
{
    Zero = 0,
    TestApple = 1,
    TestOrange = 8,
    TestBanana = 3,
};
```

Then you can create this overloaded ostream operator to get your desired behavior.

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, TestObjectClass objClass)
{
    switch (objClass)
    {
        case TestObjectClass::Zero: return os << "Zero" ;
        case TestObjectClass::TestApple: return os << "TestApple";
        case TestObjectClass::TestOrange: return os << "TestOrange";
        case TestObjectClass::TestBanana: return os << "TestBanana";
        // omit default case to trigger compiler warning for missing cases
    }
    return os << static_cast<uint16_t>(objClass);
}
```