# How do I access the an element in an enumeration by the associated number in C?

Tags: c, enums, user-defined-types

I have an enumeration in C as follows:

```
enum menu
{
    PASTA,
    PIZZA,
    DIET_COKE,
    MOJITO,
};
```

Since I haven't explicitly mentioned the integer values corresponding to these elements, they are assigned values 0,1,2, and 3 respectively.

Say I decide to add another 100 or so items to my enum.
Then is there a way to access these elements by the number they are associated with?
(Like how we can access an element of an array using its index)

Comment: Do you mean "access as a string containing its name?" The question doesn't otherwise make any sense.

Comment: I meant, say I wanted to access the fourth element, is there a way I can refer to is as menu(3)?

Comment: @Prerk but why would you want to do this? What problem dou you think you can solve with this?

Comment: Yes, access as a string containing its name,

Comment: @Prerk there are no strings here.

Comment: Possibly related C++ question: [How to Get enum item name from its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714325/how-to-get-enum-item-name-from-its-value)

Comment: @Prerk do you expect `menu(3)` to result in `"MOJITO"`, so `printf("%s", menu(3))` would print `MOJITO`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky well, I'm new to C and I want to have a list of strings, without using a 2D array. Now I thought I could just list everything I wanted to in an enum and then refer to it using the number associated with it. If you have a better suggestion then do let me know since I'm not well-versed in C and open to any other suggestions too.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes that's what i'm going for.

Comment: There are some tricky solutions such as the one I linked, but what I do is to use the text editor: first I set up the array of string literal names (a 1D array of pointers), and then I use copy/paste and find/replace to make the `enum` defintion, which is probably just as quick to set up anyway, on the rare occasions I need it.

Comment: @Prerk you can't. Once the program is compiled the identifiers like `MOJITO` are gone, just like variable names are gone. You need to write a conversion function yourself. It's about 5 + N lines of code, where N is the number of items in your menu.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh yes it sounds like a feasible solution. I'll give it a shot. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jabberwocky that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: Use a 1D array of string literal pointers, not a 2D array.

Comment: @WeatherVane a 1D array of string literal pointers is simple and efficient, but it's error prone because if you have a lot of strings and you dont pay attention, the string literal pointers might get out of alignement with the enums

Comment: @Jabberwocky everything in C is error-prone... but I take your point. It's easier to maintain if you have a function with `switch` and `case` statements to return a pointer to a string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enums are nothing but named constants in C. Same as you declare a const using

```c
#define PASTA 0
#define PIZZA 1
#define DIET_COKE 2
#define MOJITO 3
```

for example.

With the enum the compiler does that for you automatically. So there is no way to access enums in a way you want in C, unless you create an array for them.

**Update for an example**

An example use case to show how do you implement a string list with the accompany of enum as index:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *stringsOfMenu[] = {
    "Pasta",
    "Pizza",
    "Diet Coke",
    "Mojito"
};

enum menuIndex {
    PASTA,
    PIZZA,
    DIET_COKE,
    MOJITO
};

int main(void) {
    
    // For example you show menu on the screen first
    puts("Please select");
    puts("-------------");
    for(int i = 0; i <= MOJITO; i++) {
        printf("[%d] - %s\n", i+1, stringsOfMenu[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    printf("Make a choice: ");
    int choice = -1;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    
    if(choice <= 0 || choice > MOJITO+1) {
        puts("Not a valid choice");
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Note that the choice will contain the counting number.
    // That's why we convert it to the index number.
    printf("Your choice %s is in progress, thank you for your patience!\n", stringsOfMenu[choice-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

This is an output demo:

```
Please select
-------------
[1] - Pasta
[2] - Pizza
[3] - Diet Coke
[4] - Mojito

Make a choice: 2
Your choice Pizza is in progress, thank you for your patience!
```

Comment: Ah okay, that seems to make sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way I can have a list of strings, without using a 2-D array? I was going to try and use enum for that, but I now understand that it is not possible.

Comment: @Prerk define a struct line `struct Foo {enum menu; const char *dishname;}`and set up a a 1D array of `struct Foo`s.

Comment: Let me know what do you want to design exactly to be able to give you better recommendations?

Comment: @Kozmotronik Yes, I'll definitely give it a shot. Seems like that might be the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @Kozmotronik for my project, I need to write a program that lists several food items in a menu, and lets you choose items, and calculate and display a bill.

Comment: @prek hint: for this you need a struct like `struct Item {enum menu id; float price; const char *name;};`. And `struct Items items[] = {{PASTA, 8.45, "Pasta"}, {PIZZA, 9.50, "Super Pizza"}, {DIET_COKE, 3.30, "Diet Coke"}, ...}`. Don't do this without a `struct` or it will end up in tears.

Comment: You cannot create a list of strings without using 2D array. But with the help of that enum you defined the access for that array would be easier. Let me show you some example.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I think I'll try to centre my project around the idea you've given. Thank you so much for your time and effort!

Comment: @Jabberwocky I will implement using struct for sure then, thank you xD