# How to print out strings from the enum class in C++?

Tags: c++, enums

I have a C++ `Testing.hh` header file in which I have declared this ENUM -

```
enum TestTypeOpt {TestingOne, TestingTwo};
```

Now in my `Testing.cc` class I am trying to print out `TestingOne` and `TestingTwo` string from the enum as shown below

```
 cout << "From command" << Testing::TestingOne << endl;
 cout << "From command" << Testing::TestingTwo << endl;
```

But above cout prints out `0` and `1` somehow? I recently started working with C++ so little bit confuse.

Is there anything wrong I am doing? I am just trying to print actual string value from the enum class.

Comment: @arshan Read the post, he says what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Someone please correct me if there is a better approach, but the way I know to do this is with macros.

Just type `#define str(x) #x`
This replaces x with the name as it was written in the code.

Then use for example:
`cout << "From command" << str(Testing::TestingOne) << endl;`

Comment: Sure you can do this, but this is pointless if you're using a variable. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: @Qix He didn't ask for variables. He showed an explicit example and asked how to print out the names. I feel it's exactly the answer to his question.

Comment: If that's the case then just use a string. Why use a macro at all?

Comment: @Qix he is trying to print out the name of the `enum` for some reason. That's it. If you change it to a string it's not coupled to the enum/variable anymore. Using this can be very helpful for stdout debugging purposes, as you may immediately print out variable names. You are _assuming_ that he wants to print out the actual value of a enum variable as string, but that was not his question. So I don't get the -1...

Comment: No, I understand exactly what he's trying to do. I'm saying using a stringize macro is pointless if all it does is stringize. He'd just use a string in this case.

Comment: @Qix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342726/c-print-out-enum-value-as-text

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's great; that's not what the OP was asking. They were asking if what they were trying to do what possible.

Comment: @Qix Doesn't matter if asked for or not! But constitutes the better solution for the problem.

Comment: @andreee According to the marked duplicate that's the right direction to solve the problem, yes!