# How to map user input with enum value?

Tags: c++, input, enums

I have a basic `enum` declaration:

```
enum Title {Prof, Dr, Mr, Mdm, Mrs, Miss, NA};
```

I'm trying to map the user input(0,1,2,3,4,5,AnyNumber) with correct value from `enum` like this:

```
std::map<std::string,Title> m;
m["0"] = Prof;
m["1"] = Dr;
m["2"] = Mr;
m["3"] = Mdm;
m["4"] = Mrs;
m["5"] = Miss;

std::string stitle;

cout << "\n" << "Title (0:Prof 1:Dr 2:Mr 3:Mdm 4:Mrs 5:Miss Any:NA): ";
cin >> stitle;
Title title = m[stitle];
cout << title; // output 1 when I input 1, output 2 when I input 2 and so on
```

I expect the above code should be working but whatever I input will be the output from `cout` but not the value from `enum` list. What's the problem with my code?

Comment: This code does not compile.  You must be running code that's different from what you're showing here.

Comment: What's `Status` inn the `std::map<std::string,Status> m;` declaration actually? Shouldn't this be `Title`??

Comment: problem is not with code but with your expectations, `cout` will not print stringified enum

Answer (score 2):

An `enum` does not really store a series of characters as you seem to think, it just provides new names for some values of the underlying type (in your case, `int`). (This is somewhat simplified of course, but good enough to explain the observed behavior.)

Thus, printing an `enum`-element does not print its "name", but will result in the element being converted to the underlying type and then printed.

Comment: @Resolution Use the search function! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342726/c-print-out-enum-value-as-text