# why doesn't "cout << Color::green" compile?

Tags: c++, enum-class

I had this question on a test.

I know that I can do something like:

```
enum class Color { red, green = 1, blue };
Color c = Color::blue;

if( c == Color::blue )
cout << "blue\n";
```

But when I replace `cout << "blue\n";` with `cout << Color::green`, it doesn't even compile. Why doesn't it compile?

Comment: You have a lower case c in the cout call.

Comment: @Bathsheba Even with your comment I had to look thrice to see it. Well spotted. My respect.

Comment: When compiling, what actually is the error you get? And what are the warnings your get with strict level?

Comment: What did your compiler say? Ususally,when the code _'does not even compile'_, the compiler says something about the reason... :)

Comment: Uppercase doesn't work either.

Comment: I realize that the error message you get from your compilers is probably a nearly intractable wall of text. In situations like that it helps to include the initial few lines from that "wall", otherwise you run a high chance of the question being closed for not including an explanation of what is broken.

Comment: Voting to reopen, it is not a typo and, at least in this case, an error message is not needed to be answerable.

Comment: Remove `class` keyword and it will compile. Or `static_cast<int>(Color::blue)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error happens because C++ does not have a pre-defined way of printing an `enum`. You need to define an operator `<<` for printing objects of `Color` enum type according to your needs.

For example, if you would like to print the numeric value, cast the color to `int` inside your operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Color& c) {
    ostr << (int)c;
    return ostr;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/kTRcKY)

If you would like to print `enum` value as text, [see this Q&A for a sample implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3342726/335858).

Comment: Isn't the fine point here that this is a scoped enumeration? An unscoped enumeration would have utilized the library overload after a conversion