# Enum to String C++

Tags: c++, enums

I commonly find I need to convert an enum to a string in c++

I always end up doing:

```
enum Enum{ Banana, Orange, Apple } ;

char * getTextForEnum( int enumVal )
{
  switch( enumVal )
  {
  case Enum::Banana:
    return "bananas & monkeys";
  case Enum::Orange:
    return "Round and orange";
  case Enum::Apple:
    return "APPLE" ;

  default:
    return "Not recognized..";
  }
}
```

Is there a better or recognized idiom for doing this?

Comment: Perhaps use `std::map<int, std::string>` instead of enum and switch? With a bit of wrapping into an object you could make it smart enough to be reusable as an error code lookup and handler for all your apps.

Comment: One improvement is to omit the 'default:' clause whilst turning up the warning level on your compiler and treating warnings as errors. This way, if you ever extend the list of enums, the compiler will warn and fail on your switch statement, reminding you to extend the switch as well.  Some people say you should always have a default, but I believe this is a scenario where the lack of can actually help you.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
enum Enum{ Banana, Orange, Apple } ;
static const char * EnumStrings[] = { "bananas & monkeys", "Round and orange", "APPLE" };

const char * getTextForEnum( int enumVal )
{
  return EnumStrings[enumVal];
}
```

Comment: Works only for continuous enums.

Comment: @SasQ, I have a more extensive answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11586083/5987 Lots of other good suggestions in that thread too.

Comment: A better prototype would be `const char *getTextForEnum(int) const;` my friend. Best practice.

Comment: @GangaiJohann that's only if it's a member function. My practice is to make as few changes to the code presented in the question as possible, to avoid unnecessary distractions.

Comment: And there is a code generator for that: http://www.th-thielemann.de/tools/cpp-enum-to-string.html

Comment: @Th.Thielemann's comment should be the answer to this question. Thanks for making that!

Comment: how can I go the other way? I want an enum from a string

Comment: @ekkis I'd use `std::map<std::string,enum>`.

Comment: This does not work for enums with negative values assigned. The `std::map` approach would work, though.

Comment: What about `getTextForEnum(500)` ?
I think you should add last element like *FRUITS_MAX* and then in the function compare if given argument is smaller than this new last enum.

Answer (score 24):

Kind of an anonymous lookup table rather than a long switch statement:

```
return (const char *[]) {
    "bananas & monkeys",
    "Round and orange", 
    "APPLE",
}[enumVal];
```

Answer (score 15):

You could throw the enum value and string into an STL map. Then you could use it like so.

```
   return myStringMap[Enum::Apple];
```