# How to use cereal to serialize enum types with magic_enum?

Tags: c++, cereal

I tried to use magic_enum with cereal to serialize a enum type.
Here is my code, and it's worked on serialize but got an error with deserialize.

```cpp
template <class Archive,
        cereal::traits::EnableIf<cereal::traits::is_text_archive<Archive>::value>
        = cereal::traits::sfinae, class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, std::string> save_minimal( Archive &, const T& h )
{
    return std::string(magic_enum::enum_name(h));
}

template <class Archive,
        cereal::traits::EnableIf<cereal::traits::is_text_archive<Archive>::value>
        = cereal::traits::sfinae, class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, void> load_minimal( Archive const &, T& enumType, std::string const& str)
{
    enumType = magic_enum::enum_cast<T>(str).value();
}

enum class Color {RED, BLUE, YELLOW};

int main()
{
    Color c = Color::RED;
    std::ifstream is("c.json");
    cereal::JSONOutputArchive outAr(os);
    out(CEREAL_NVP(c));
}
```

output:

```json
{
    "c": "RED"
}
```

but when I tried to deserialize the c.json file, I got an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdwpc.png)

here is the callstack:

```cpp
cerealtest.exe!rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>,rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>>::GetInt() Line 1744   C++

cerealtest.exe!cereal::JSONInputArchive::loadValue<int,0>(int & val) Line 700   C++

cerealtest.exe!cereal::load<int,0>(cereal::JSONInputArchive & ar, int & t) Line 1115    C++
 
cerealtest.exe!cereal::InputArchive<cereal::JSONInputArchive,0>::processImpl<int,0>(int & t) Line 942   C++
 
cerealtest.exe!cereal::InputArchive<cereal::JSONInputArchive,0>::process<int &>(int & head) Line 854    C++
 
cerealtest.exe!cereal::InputArchive<cereal::JSONInputArchive,0>::processImpl<enum Color,0>(Color & t) Line 963  C++
```

here is my code to deserialize c.json.

```cpp
int main()
{
    Color c;
    std::ifstream is("c.json");
    cereal::JSONInputArchive in(is);
    in(CEREAL_NVP(c));
}
```

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969621/how-to-use-cereal-to-serialize-enum-types/50416878#50416878) is exaltly what I wanted. But I don't know why the deserialize function din't work.

Comment: As always, post exception text and code as text blocks, rather than images. Posting the call-stack as a text-block might also have given an insight into the exception.

Comment: I've been posting the call-stack as a text-block. Thanks for your advice! It's my first time posting a question.