# accessing enum members by int values

Tags: c++, enums

I have

```
enum Direction { NONE = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, FORWARD };
```

and there is a function

```
void displayDirection(int dir)
{ ... }
```

This function will take an int value and will print the members of "Direction" according to that value. How can it be possible? Thanks in advance.

ex: if dir = 0 print NONE; if dir = 1, print RIGHT; etc.

PS: I am very new at c++.

Comment: Isn't this already covered on about a [dozen different questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+enum+int+convert)

Answer (score 3):

you need "string" versions of them to print... e.g. `char* szArray[] = { "NONE", "LEFT", "RIGHT", "FORWARD" };` then in `displayDirection` reference it via `szArray[dir]`.  bounds-checking would be appropriate as well...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, because `enum` values are, under the hood, integral types. The conversion is implicit, so you should be able to directly call

```
displayDirection(3);  //FORWARD
```

However, I suggest changing the function signature to

```
void displayDirection(Direction dir)
```

Comment: I didnt understand how can it be possible with 1st function, what should be the inside of that function. And I want to do it by int parameter, i try to learn

Comment: @Mustafa how *what* can be possible?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore what should be the definition of displayDirection(3) function, i think it is impossible according to other answers

Comment: @LuchianGrigore okay, how can I print "FORWARD" when I call displayDirection(3); ?

Comment: @Mustafa see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201593/is-there-a-simple-script-to-convert-c-enum-to-string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the text values, "NONE", "LEFT" etc, that is not directly possible.

In the compiled executable, the names have been optimised away and you can't get them back, just like you can't reference variables by name (like "dir" in your example).

So what you should do is put the names into your program by store them in a string array.