# C++ copy #define to char array

Tags: c++, c, char, c-preprocessor

I have the following declaration:

```
#define ERROR   0x01
..
UINT32 res=ERROR;
```

Is it possible, given just the variable `res`, to copy the string `"ERROR"` into a char array?

**CLARIFICATION**:

Maybe I wasn't clear enough.
I'm calling a DLL which return values. 
Those values can be interpreted like this:

```
switch (res)
{
    case ERROR:
     strcpy(arr, "ERROR");break;
    case ... 
}
```

since there are many options and the `switch` will be huge, I wandered maybe there is a shortcut...

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to ask... Please give some example, illustration.

Comment: Before compilation, there is a Preprocessor program which accepts your program with preprocessing statements, turns it into a pure form of program without preprocessing statements. Hence, `ERROR` is replaced with `0x01` wherever in the program,  even before compilation starts.. If yours is a C program compiling with gcc: try `gcc -E file_name.c` to get the pre-processed output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple script to convert C++ enum to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201593/is-there-a-simple-script-to-convert-c-enum-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define ERROR   0x01
```

defines constant integral literal `0x01` and preprocessor turns the following line:

```
UINT32 res = ERROR;
```

into:

```
UINT32 res = 0x01;
```

before the compilation starts. There is no *char array*.

---

In case you want to copy associated name of constant to avoid doing something like:

```
case ERROR:
 strcpy(arr, "ERROR"); break;
case X:
 strcpy(arr, "X"); break;
case Y:
 strcpy(arr, "Y"); break;
...
```

then you might create a helper with static structure retrieving name by given code, yet for the sake of type safety I would avoid `#define`s as much as possible. Something like (this is just a concept):

```
const char* getRetCodeName(const UINT32 code) {
    static std::map<int, const char*> codes;
    static int firstCall = 1;
    if (firstCall) {
        codes[ERROR] = "ERROR";
        codes[X] = "X";
        codes[Y] = "Y";
        firstCall = 0;
    }
    return codes[code];
}
```

and in caller's code:

```
UINT32 res = someCall();
const char* retCodeName = getRetCodeName(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this without depending on the name `ERROR`, but you can do something like this:

```
const char* value_to_string(UINT32 val) {
  #define CHECK_CONSTANT(maConst) \
    if (val == maConst) return #maConst

  CHECK_CONSTANT(ERROR);
  return 0;

  #undef CHECK_CONSTANT
}
```

This abstracts from the value of the macro, but unfortunately it cannot abstract from its name. If you have more than one such `#define`, you can also list them all as subsequent `CHECK_CONSTANT(something);` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display the name of the define? This is not possible.
Perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
myString=(res==ERROR)?"ERROR":"OK"
```