# How to print names on a multidimensional array in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program to print the names of  an array, the array represents the first row of the chess board.  My attempt is with the following program but the only thing that I can achieve is printing numbers :( .

```
    #include <iostream>

     using namespace std;

      void  main()

       enum pions // giving the names in pions 
       { 
       Tower=1 ,
       Horse ,
       Officer ,
       Princes ,
       King };

     int Chess [0][8]={Tower , Horse , officer , Princes , King , Officer , Horse , Tower };    

     // putting the names of each coordinate in the array (above ) .

    cout << " in this place the pion that is placed is the  " << chess [0][1] << endl;
```

I know that the program will print  the number 2 , but how can I make it print the word "Horse"  instead of  2 ???

The cout command  is written by the creator of the program (me :P) how i can give the option to the user to choose the part of the array that is going to be printed  ?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort, a big sorry in case I am  not clear, its my first post :D .

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Your first problem is that you have an array of ints, not Strings or pions as you call them.

Comment: The declaration `int Chess [0][8]` makes a zero-sized array of arrays, which is not quite what you want I'm guessing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple script to convert C++ enum to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201593/is-there-a-simple-script-to-convert-c-enum-to-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function that takes a parameter of type `Chess` and returns a string. Here's one that would work:

```
const char *chessPieceName(Chess piece)
{
    switch(piece) {
        case Tower:
            return "Tower";
            break;
        case Horse:
            return "Horse";
            break;
        // etc.
        default:
            return "Not a valid piece";
            break;
    }
}
```

You can call then call this function from `main`:

```
cout << " in this place the pion that is placed is the  " << chessPieceName(chess[0][1]) << endl;
```

Having said that, you have numerous other issues in your code that should prevent it from compiling. I'm not going to go through them, since you seem to just be interested in the question you asked.

Comment: Please note that the compiler will not even issue a warning for incorrectly calling a knight a horse. ;-)

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the switch statement instead of an array of names.

Comment: Thank you, This was really helpful!! Will try to combine it with Daniel's answer!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Using a switch statement has the advantage that it works even if the values of the `enum` are defined to be something other than the default.

Comment: godel9 It is a very bad style of programming. For example the enum can be changed but you forgot to change the function. Or you will change the function but because it contains so much code you can omit the break statement and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `translator` function that takes the `int` value and transforms it into a printable string value:

```
string translate(int piecenum){
    string [5] ref = { "Tower", "Horse", "Officer", "Princes" "King"}
    return ref[piecenum];
}
```

You can print them out using `cout << translate(chess[0][1]) << endl`

Comment: Why take the the value by `int` instead of by it's actual type?

Comment: Because the OP initialized `chess` to type `int` (wrongly though)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print out identifiers of the enum.

You need to create a different function which takes your enum as an input parameter and returns an std::string with the name you want. For example, if you pass it `pions::Tower`, it will return "Tower". If you pass it `pions::Horse`, it will return "Horse". Etc.

Hint: Use a `switch` statement in the body of that function, as [godel9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911082/96780) illustrates.

Comment: First of all there will be much code and it will be difficult to support it

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Maybe for you it doesn make any sense. As for me it is a bad style of programming when you hard code a set of literals in the body of some function.

Comment: @Vlad This has absolutely nothing to do with the switch statement. You could define the string constants in a separate place and then use each of them in each section of the switch statement. In production code, I use string constants isolated in the appropriate text modules, to make internationalization easy, but in a SO answer I can just suggest a correct answer to the OP, and he will take care of his strings in the way he likes best. My answer is correct, since it will provide a correct solution to the OP's problem. The fact that you don't like its style is not relevant to its correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Either use C# instead of C++ or define yourself an array of chess figure names. For example

```
   enum pions // giving the names in pions 
   { 
   Tower = 0 , // <== I prefer to use 0 instead of 1
   Horse ,
   Officer ,
   Princes ,
   King };


const char *name = { "Tower", "Horse", "Officer", "Princes", "King" };

//...

for ( int i : chess[0] ) std::cout << name[i] << std::endl;
```