# Is there a simple way to convert an enum class to a string (c++)?

Tags: c++, enum-class

while there are solutions to easily [convert an enum to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201593/is-there-a-simple-script-to-convert-c-enum-to-string#answer-201665), I would like the extra safety benefits of using `enum class`. Is there a simple way to convert an `enum class` to a string?

(The solution given doesn't work, as enum class can't index an array).

Comment: You could use a `std::unordered_map` instead.

Comment: _"The solution given doesn't work, as enum class can't index an array"_ Can you elaborate about this, or give a sample? I don't understand in which way it should be different for `enum class`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You cannot implicitly convert an `enum class` to its underlying type, which is kind of the point of them.

Comment: Array-based solutions aren't usable when the vaues in the enum are user-specified, like { Good= 1, Bad= 2, Unknown= ~0 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implicitly convert to the underlying type but you can do it explicitly.

```
enum class colours : int { red, green, blue };
const char *colour_names[] = { "red", "green", "blue" };
colours mycolour = colours::red;
cout << "the colour is" << colour_names[static_cast<int>(mycolour)];
```

It's up to you if that is too verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using VS C++. Below the code example of MSDN

```
using namespace System;
public ref class EnumSample
{
public:
   enum class Colors
   {
      Red = 1,
      Blue = 2
   };

   static void main()
   {
      Enum ^ myColors = Colors::Red;
      Console::WriteLine( "The value of this instance is '{0}'", myColors );
   }

};

int main()
{
   EnumSample::main();
}

/*
Output.
The value of this instance is 'Red'.
*/
```

Comment: What about { Red= 0x100, Blue= 0x10000, Green= 0x1000000 } ?

Comment: Brilliant SSCE, could you explain the `^` syntax to me as I'm not familiar with it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, with c++cli I found an explanation of the syntax  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)