# c++: Using X Macro to define enum and string array inside class?

Tags: c++, string, enums

Using C++ (Visual Studio).  I'm trying to find a solution for converting an enum to a string.  I came across X Macros (http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401387) which seems to be a reasonable solution but I'm having a hard time getting it to work inside of a class.  All the examples I've seen show everything defined outside of a class.

```
// ColorNames.h
X(Red, "Red"),
X(Blue, "Blue"),
...


// MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();

    #define X(a, b) a
    enum Colors {
        #include "ColorNames.h"
    };
    #undef X

    #define X(a, b) b
    char *colorNameStrings_[] = {
        #include "ColorNames.h"
    };
    #undef X
}
```

The IDE chokes on the line `*colorNameStrings_[] =...` I guess because you can't initialize a data member variable in the header file?  How do I get this to work?

Comment: My goal is to have an enum to string mapping.  The idea of X Macros, I believe, is to help guarantee that mapping stays in sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't initialize a non static constant inside a class definition.

You would probably have to do it like that:

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();

    #define X(a, b) a
    enum Colors {
        #include "ColorNames.h"
    };
    #undef X

    static const char * colorNameStrings_[];
};
```

And in the .cpp file:

```
// MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

#define X(a, b) b
const char * MyClass::colorNameStrings_[] = {
    #include "ColorNames.h"
};
#undef X
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using X-Macros, consider using [the Boost.Preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).  The initial, one-time definition of the code generation macros takes a bit of work, but the end result is far cleaner and much easier to reuse.

I provided a basic implementation of a generic, Boost.Preprocessor-based enum-to-string-name conversion in an answer to ["How to convert an enum type variable to a string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093460/how-to-convert-an-enum-type-variable-to-a-string/5094430#5094430)

Answer (score 1):

Use a struct like this

```
struct convert
{
     std::map<MyEnum, std::string> mapping;

     convert() 
     { 
          mapping[SOME_ENUM_VALUE] = "SomeValue"; 
          // etc to fill map
     }

     std::string operator()(MyEnum enum)
     {
         return mapping[enum];    
     }

};
```

Then use like this:

```
convert c;
std::string ret = c(myenum);  //calls operator()
```

Comment: That is ridiculously verbose. Also, why use a struct when a function would do?

Comment: @Etienne, that's just how I used to do it, when I had loads of enums in need of conversion.

Comment: A benefit of doing it with a struct is that you can define them in more varied scope.  With a function you are restricted from inline in a function and fully in a header.

Comment: The basic problem with this that X Macros tries to solve is that the programmer must remember to keep the enum and the std::map in sync.