# associating enums with strings in C

Tags: c, string, enums

I have seen this link

[How to convert enum names to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c)

I have a series of `enums` defined in the following manner in client provided library header file (which I can't change):

Also the enums are sparse .

```
typedef enum
{
    ERROR_NONE=59,   
    ERROR_A=65,  
    ERROR_B=67
}
```

I want to print these values in my function for instance I would like to print `ERROR_NONE` instead of `59`. Is there a better way of just using `switch` `case` or `if else` constructs to get this done ?
Example

```
   int Status=0;
   /* some processing in library where Status changes to 59 */
   printf("Status = %d\n",Status); /* want to print ERROR_NONE instead of 59 */
```

Comment: Why not use the [stringizing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x(v=vs.80).aspx)? Can you show us some code where you are trying to print these enum values?

Answer (score 3):

A direct application of stringizing operator might be helpful

```
#define stringize(x) #x

printf("%s\n", stringize(ERROR_NONE));
```

You've mentioned that you cant change the library file. If you decide otherwise :), you can use `X` macros as follows

```
enumstring.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAMES C(RED)C(GREEN)C(BLUE)

#define C(x) x,

enum color { NAMES TOP };

#undef C

#define C(x) #x,

const char * const color_name[] = { NAMES };

int main( void ) 
{ printf( "The color is %s.\n", color_name[ RED ]);  
  printf( "There are %d colors.\n", TOP ); }

stdout
The color is RED. 
There are 3 colors.
```

Read more [here](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~ram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/c_preprocessor_applications_en)

**EDIT**: With the specific example you are showing us, I am afraid, `switch-case` is the nearest you can get, especially when you have sparse `enums`.

Comment: You need a two step macro to force both expansion and stringization. See http://c-faq.com/ansi/stringize.html.

Answer (score 2):

[FAQ 11.17](http://c-faq.com/ansi/stringize.html). Use the `xstr()` macro. You should probably use that:

```
 #define str(x) #x
 #define xstr(x) str(x)

 printf("%s\n", xstr(ERROR_A));
```