# Can an initialization of an enum be automated?

Tags: c, enums

I am having a file of strings by which I want to create an enum with values named by the strings. For example the list is:

```
"a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

I would like to get an enum like this

```
enum SomeEnum { a, b, c, d };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to generate C source code for an enum, or that you want to generate an enum at runtime? The former is easy if you know how to read and write files, the latter is not possible. If it is the former, please specify what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I think that would work, I could just write out a .h file with the enum in it. Thanks.

Comment: This sort of question has already been asked many times before: possible duplicate of [How to convert enum names to string in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use X-Macros, then you only need to place your enum/string in the `myfile.h`.

### myFile.h

```
#ifndef ENUM_CONVERT
#define ENUM_CONVERT(val)  val
#define ENUM_HEADER enum SomeEnum
#endif

ENUM_HEADER
{
ENUM_CONVERT(a),
ENUM_CONVERT(b),
ENUM_CONVERT(c),
ENUM_CONVERT(d)
};
```

### myFile.c

```
#include "myFile.h"  // This declares the enum
#define MKSTR(a)           #a
#define ENUM_CONVERT(val)  MKSTR(val)
#define ENUM_HEADER        char *myStrList[]=
#include "myFile.h"  // This defines the stringList
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use any of the popular scripting languages (perl, python, tcl) and parse the file and generate enums that you like.

Comment: or a clever text editor if the work needs to be done only once.

Comment: @wap26: I definitively agree :).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult in c to convert string into a variable