# How to check the value of errno?

Tags: c, system-calls, errno

I am using a system call and in case it fails, I need to do different things for different errnos.

I need to write code that looks something like this:

```
int res;
res = systemCall();
if (res == -1)
{
    if (errno == ENOMSG)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

perror doesn't help, because it only prints the value.

As for strerro - if it is what I need, I am not suer how to use it, because [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) it says that the actual string is not the same as the error. Quote from the man page: "(For example, if errnum is EINVAL, the returned description will be "Invalid argument")".

I am using Linux.
System calls: msgsend and msgrcv (https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv). I am not sure what C libraries you are asking about.

I see I didn't explain myself well.

Is the statement if (errno == ENOMSG) valid? Is there such a variable errno? Basically my question is: What should go in the `if` statement in order to test the errno?

Comment: On what operating system? What exact system call? What C library? Please **edit your question to improve it**

Comment: Each system call has a list of possible errno values (see it's `man` page), this will let you know what you should test against.

Comment: What you've written is fine.  Remember, no library function sets `errno` to zero, and you shouldn't test it unless a function indicates an error and is documented to set `errno`.  Note that many pthreads functions don't set `errno`, for example; they return the error number instead.  Also, functions can set `errno` to a non-zero value even if successful.  For example, on Solaris, if standard output is not a terminal, `errno` can be set to ENOTTY even though the `printf()` call is successful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume you are using Linux, and I suppose that you don't *directly* use the system call, but some of the (simple) wrappers (from your C library) listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Notice that some weird system calls are not wrapped by the C library (a well known example of unwrapped system call would be [sigreturn(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html) which you probably should never use). Quite often the C library is [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), but it might be [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) etc. Notice also that kernel raw system calls have different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) than ordinary C function (so in practice a libc wrapper is required, and is in charge of dealing with `errno`). Notice also that [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is generally a macro (almost behaving as some variable).

The [msgrcv(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgrcv.2.html) man page documents that `errno`  could be one of `E2BIG`, `EACCES` , `EFAULT` ... `ENOMSG`, `ENOSYS`  ... (refer to that man page to get the list of all possible errors).

So you would code something like

```
ssize_t siz = msgrcv(msqid, msgp, msgsz, msgtyp, msgflg);
if (siz<0) { // msgrcv failed and has set errno
  if (errno == ENOMSG) 
    dosomething();
  else if (errno == EAGAIN) 
    dosomethingelse();
  /// etc
  else {  
     syslog(LOG_DAEMON|LOG_ERR, "msgrcv failure with %s\n",
            strerror(errno)); 
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  };
};
```

> Is the statement `if (errno == ENOMSG)` .... valid?

Yes it is; you want to test `errno`  only after some system call failure (e.g. when `siz<0`).

> Is there such a variable `errno`?

Not any more. Please read carefully  [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) documentation. You should not declare `extern int errno;` (this was possible in the 1980s, not in 21<sup>st</sup> century) but you should *always* `#include <errno.h>` and use `errno`  as if it was a variable, but it is almost always some macro (whose definition appears in `/usr/include/bits/errno.h` which is included by `/usr/include/errno.h`).

BTW, SysV-style facilities tend to become obsolete and are not always available. I recommend using POSIX message queues facilities, read [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html).

You might want to read the freely downloadable [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) (an old book; you can buy something better & newer) and/or all the man pages reachable from [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) & [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html).

Comment: The link to the Advanced Linux Programming download may be broken or out of date.  Doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Corrected, with some random link working today. Actually, better read a newer book if you can afford it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I'll search for something newer.  Would be glad to hear suggestions if anything comes to mind.

Comment: I did gave a link to a copy of ALP which today is downloadable. You are allowed to redistribute it (but IANAL)

Comment: Highly recommend The Linux Programming Interface (https://man7.org/tlpi/). Also suggest looking at warn(3) and err(3).  Very often, when an error occurs, all you want to do is splat a message about the error, with some context (e.g. a filename) and possibly just quit.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden Now if only they were standardised by POSIX...

Answer (score 36):

How to check the value of `errno`:

1. You will need to `#include <errno.h>`.
2. Yes, you can definitely say things like `if(errno == ENOENT) { ... }`, and that is the common and recommended way of doing it.
3. In general, do *not* use `errno` to determine that an error has occurred.  Check the return value of the function, and if the return value indicates an error, then check `errno` to see what the error was. (More on this below.)
4. `errno` looks like a variable, but it actually isn't.  This doesn't concern you as long as you just say things like `if(errno == ENOENT) { ... }`.  But you probably shouldn't try to do something like `int errno_ptr = &errno;`.
5. You can use functions like `perror()` and `strerror()` to get human-readable error strings corresponding to `errno` values.  But, yes, the strings you get are generally things like "No such file or directory".  There is no good way that I know of to convert the errno value `ENOENT` to the string `"ENOENT"`.  (Addendum: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885360) for some answers.)

To say a little more about #3.  Sometimes it's tempting to say something like

```
errno = 0;
printf("Hello, world!\n");
if(errno != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "printf failed!\n");
}
```

But don't do that.  Instead do

```
int retval = printf("Hello, world!\n");
if(retval < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "printf failed!\n");
}
```

The reason is that, somewhere in the process of doing its job, `printf` might have done something that resulted in an error, something that set `errno`, but `printf` might have recovered from that error and gone on to complete successfully.

There are a very few library functions that are guaranteed *not* to touch errno if there wasn't an error (I think one example might be `strtol`), but in general, this is something you have to be careful of.

To say a little more about #4.  `errno` looks like a variable, and more specifically, it looks like a global variable.  But of course global variables are bad.  But `errno` has been around forever; there are tens of millions of lines of code that use it; it's still basically pretty convenient; it's too late to "fix" it.  So, instead, if you peek behind the curtain, you'll find that most implementations do something like

```
extern int *__errno_pointer;
#define errno (*__errno_pointer)
```

or

```
extern int *__errno_pointer_function();
#define errno (*__errno_function())
```

In this way, they can arrange for `errno` to work reasonably properly even in, say, multithreaded code.

Comment: `extern int __errno_pointer;` Did you mean `extern int *__errno_pointer;`?

Comment: @user16217248 I certainly did.  Good grief.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Include errno.h

Some examples:

```
// Error codes
#define EPERM        1  /* Operation not permitted */
#define ENOENT       2  /* No such file or directory */
#define ESRCH        3  /* No such process */
#define EINTR        4  /* Interrupted system call */
#define EIO          5  /* I/O error */
#define ENXIO        6  /* No such device or address */
#define E2BIG        7  /* Argument list too long */
#define ENOEXEC      8  /* Exec format error */
#define EBADF        9  /* Bad file number */
#define ECHILD      10  /* No child processes */
#define EAGAIN      11  /* Try again */
#define ENOMEM      12  /* Out of memory */
#define EACCES      13  /* Permission denied */
#define EFAULT      14  /* Bad address */
#define ENOTBLK     15  /* Block device required */
#define EBUSY       16  /* Device or resource busy */
#define EEXIST      17  /* File exists */
#define EXDEV       18  /* Cross-device link */
#define ENODEV      19  /* No such device */
#define ENOTDIR     20  /* Not a directory */
#define EISDIR      21  /* Is a directory */
#define EINVAL      22  /* Invalid argument */
#define ENFILE      23  /* File table overflow */
#define EMFILE      24  /* Too many open files */
#define ENOTTY      25  /* Not a typewriter */
#define ETXTBSY     26  /* Text file busy */
#define EFBIG       27  /* File too large */
#define ENOSPC      28  /* No space left on device */
#define ESPIPE      29  /* Illegal seek */
#define EROFS       30  /* Read-only file system */
#define EMLINK      31  /* Too many links */
#define EPIPE       32  /* Broken pipe */
#define EDOM        33  /* Math argument out of domain of func */
#define ERANGE      34  /* Math result not representable */
```

Your implementation may have more errno includes, like for example `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`.