# cannot create a posix message queue

Tags: c, posix, message-queue

I am trying to create a POSIX message queue but mq_open() returns -1 all the time. Here is my code. What might be the reason? How can I understand?

```
mqd_t mq;
struct mq_attr attr;
mq = mq_open("/randomMq", (O_RDONLY | O_CREAT), 0666, &attr);
printf("%d\n",mq);
```

Comment: "On error, mq_open() returns (mqd_t) -1, **with errno set to indicate the error**.", says the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mq_open.2.html). So what's the [value of errno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46014661/300836)? Perhaps try a quick [perror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means)...

Comment: Thank you. errno returns "Function not implemented". I think that means posix queues are not implemented on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows subsystem which I am using.

Answer (score 3):

As you've now discovered by checking errno, it seems like [neither System V messages nor POSIX message queues are currently implemented in the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1443).