# how can a function return an lvalue in c?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

i read in **The Linux Programming Interface 29-2 Threads and errno** the next :

> On Linux, a thread-specific errno is achieved in a similar manner to most other UNIX implementations: errno is defined as a macro that expands into a function call returning a modifiable lvalue that is distinct for each thread.

and i wondered how can a function return a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: A function cannot return a modifiable lvalue.  But a function can return a pointer, and `errno` can be defined as a macro that expands to something like `*per_thread_errno_function()`.  So the function does not return an lvalue, but the expansion of the `errno` macro is an lvalue. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013418/how-to-check-the-value-of-errno/46014661#46014661).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the macro that "returns" the modifiable lvalue, not the function call itself. The function returns a pointer and the macro dereferences this pointer. For example, [`errno.h`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/errno.h) of the glibc source code defines the macro `errno` like this:

```
# define errno (*__errno_location ())
```

This wording is a bit misleading:

> `errno` is defined as a macro that expands into a function call returning a modifiable lvalue that is distinct for each thread.

A more accurate wording would be:

> `errno` is defined as a macro that expands into **an expression that contains a function call. This expression evaluates to** a modifiable lvalue that is distinct for each thread.