# How to print all the contents in enum in C?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, enums

I am trying to print all of the content in enum in a single line using the tab to separate each shirt size. When I try to compile my program it prints out random numbers instead of S,M,L,XL.

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

enum SIZE{S,M,L,XL};

  int i,j;

int main()
{
enum SIZE s;

int t[4][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

  int *p=t;

/********DISPLAY ARRAY******************/

printf("This is our inventory \n");

  for(s=S; s<=XL; s=(s+1))
  {
      printf("%d \t", t[s]);
  }

   printf("\n");

 for( i=0; i<4; i++)
 {
    for(j=0;j<4; j++)
      {
            printf("%d\t", *p++);
      }


    printf("\n");
 }
/*****************************************/

printf("\n\n");
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

---

```
output:

This is our inventory
2686668         2686684         2686700         2686716
1       2       3       4
5       6       7       8
9       1       2       3
4       5       6       7
```

Press any key to continue . . .

---

I don't understand why the following line is being printed out:

```
2686668         2686684         2686700         2686716
```

as opposed to:

```
S             M               L              XL
```

Can someone explain what is causing this to occur?

Comment: `t` is declared as a 2D array, but you are printing it as a 1D array!

Comment: Might want to study what an enum is before using one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enums in C don't have names (see [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html))

Try this instead: [How to convert enum names to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Longhup answer, you can use X-Macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZES \
    X(S) \
    X(M) \
    X(L) \
    X(XL)  

#define X(a) a,
enum SIZE{SIZES};
#undef X

#define X(a) #a,
static char *arr[] = {SIZES};
#undef X

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= XL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
printf("%d \t", t[s]);
```

is printing out *pointer* values (`&t[s][0]`), not the values of the enumeration type, hence the weird numbers.

Unfortunately, there's no magic to enumeration constants that allows you to display the identifier based on the corresponding value.  I usually use an array of strings corresponding to the enum identifiers.