# Check if string is valid enum in C

Tags: c, string, enums

I am trying to figure out if there is a better way to test if a string being entered at the command line is a valid enum entry for a C program.

Is there a better way to test the entries in an enum instead of saying:

```
if((!strcmp(string, "NUM0")) && (!strcmp(string, "NUM1")))
{
    printf("Invalid entry\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: You need to use `strcmp()` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't answer my question.

Comment: I think it did, since your method will not work at all.

Comment: A string cannot be an `enum`! And how to compare strings in C has been asked a million times already! Please do at least minimal research before asking.

Comment: No, all the answers are given in C#.  I did do a search... for like 3 hours.  Please see the answer below.  He actually read my question and answered it brilliantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it this way:

```
enum opt {NUM0, NUM1, NUM2, OPT_END};
static const char *opt_str[OPT_END] = {"NUM0", "NUM1", "NUM2"};

enum opt i;
for (i = 0; i < OPT_END; ++i)
   if (strcmp(string, opt_str[i]) == 0) break;

if (i == OPT_END) {
    puts("Invalid entry");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
/* do something with i */
```

Additionally, you could employ [x-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to ensure your enums and strings are in sync: [How to convert enum names to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966395/1257035).

Comment: That's pretty slick, thank you.  The list I have is pretty big, so this will make every a lot more compact.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2470057 You can use [x-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to auto-generate if the list is long.

Comment: For the sake of robustness I'd do `... char *opt_str[OPT_END] = ...`

Comment: Also why not make `i` of type `enum opt`?

Comment: @alk, thanks for the suggestions. Amended the answer.

Comment: @user2470057 You're welcome. If your question is answered, please show so by marking an answer as accepted.

Comment: I was going to earlier, but they have a timer set on it.  I guess they want to make sure other people get a chance to answer.  Anyway, yes, answer accepted.  I totally love the way you implemented this whole thing.