# Is there a simple way to convert value to string?

Tags: c

I have defined some macros like this:

```
#define ABC '1'
#define DEF '2'
#define XYZ '3'
```

And I also need to output the macro string based on its value, like this:

```
static const char* get_event_string(unsigned char event)
{
    switch (event) {
        case '1':
            return "ABC";
        case '2':
            return "DEF";
        case '3':
            return "XYZ";
    }
}
```

Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: Seems simple enough. What exactly do you try to achieve?

Comment: Why are you using `'1'` in your case statements when you have perfectly usable `#define`'d labels set up?

Comment: Close enough if you don't mind using enums instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to have actual *digits* (as encoded characters) for your `event`? If not, suggest to just use numbers starting from `0` (or from `1` if you need `0` for some special value like "no event") -- this would also make the alternative approach shown in my answer *simpler* (you wouldn't even *need* a function any more) and enable you to use a preprocessor trick like in the question linked by @HolyBlackCat.

Comment: Are `ABC,DEF,XYZ` sequential  values like `'1','2','3'`?

Comment: too broad, please detail what you want, here we don't really understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is already a common way to do it. I'd recommend to keep it this way and just actually *use* your macros in the `case` statements instead of the *magic char*s.

If your values are contiguous, you could also use a lookup table like this:

```
static const char *get_event_string(unsigned char event)
{
    static const char *const names[] = {
        "ABC",
        "DEF",
        "XYZ"
    };
    return names[event - '1'];
}
```

Both approaches assume that the functions are never called with invalid parameters.

---

If you can change the values of your events to natural numbers like e.g.

```
#define ABC 1
#define DEF 2
#define XYZ 3
```

or maybe even using an `enum`:

```
enum event
{
    EV_NONE,
    EV_ABC,
    EV_DEF,
    EV_XYZ
};
```

then a lookup table will have a real benefit: You don't need a function any more. Just define it (as an example for the `enum` above):

```
const char *const event_strings[] = {
    "EV_NONE",
    "EV_ABC",
    "EV_DEF",
    "EV_XYZ"
};
```

And all you have to write in code to access the name is `event_strings[event]`.

Doing it *this* way even enables you to use the preprocessor to automate defining a matching table to your `enum` like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966395/2371524).

Comment: That has too many redundancies and is error-prone. The least would be to use designated initialisers for the array. And as you already use a function to retriever the data, it would be better to move the table to function-scope and make the table itself `const`, too.

Comment: Well I wouldn't use *digit characters* as IDs in my code, to start with. Maybe I'll edit this to show the (IMHO) best way when you just use natural numbers as IDs....

Comment: actually good hint about the `const` table, that's better (no matter whether using a function or not)

Comment: A function with a local `static` if better wrt information hiding and namespace-pollution. For a longer table, I agree this is better at file-scope, but it definitively should have internal linkage.

Comment: @Olaf I disagree about internal linkage as soon as there isn't a function any more. And I *have* internal linkage in the example *with* a function. In this case, putting the table inside function scope seems sensible.

Comment: What if the name-space is reduced? If the access changes? Using a getter-function is the recommended way; one should not hav global data between modules. That also leaves range-checking/assertions to a single function, not sprinkled all around the code using that table. It also simplifies debugging, etc. There is a reason global variables are considered bad practice. The little - if any speed improvement is negligible. Using LTO completely negates this as an advantage.

Comment: @Olaf you should know very well that there's no "absolute rule" in programming and a constant lookup table for some enum names is IMHO a good use of a "shared global".

Comment: I do very well, but as we can't cover all areas , we should present best practice; exceptions can be learned later when necessary. A function is much more flexible without changing the interface. Direct access to a table is problematic (see my assertion/debug issue) and too inflexible.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out this fine answer first: [How to convert enum names to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966395/2410359)

---

If that does not meet your needs, compute an index based on the various constants.

If the constants `ABC,DEF,XYZ` are unique, arbitrary (e.g. maybe not sequential) and the constant count fixed (3), could use a formula and let the compiler optimize.

```
const char* get_event_string(unsigned char event) {
  int index = (event == ABC)*1
            | (event == DEF)*2
            | (event == XYZ)*3;
  static const char *event_string[4] = { "None", "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ" };
  return event_string[index];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, sure this is better than letting the compiler optimize a `switch .. case`? I find it less readable, but that's probably a matter of taste.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Good point.  No suggestion that this is "better" in emitted code than a `switch .. case`.  Depending on OP's needs, this does place the `event_string[]` as an array that may be easier to maintain.  Of course one could code `case '1': return event_string[1]; case '2':
            return event_string[2]; ...`  IMO best to code for clarity and using a `switch ... case` is _usually_ clear enough yet OP's needs may be different than my experience.

Comment: Should not be a concern for 10-20 strings, but wont log(n) range comparisons be better than n equality checks?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya if the values are really arbitrarily distributed, you will have these equality checks when claculating the `index`. So, still unsure about that. But it's definitely an interesting approach :)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya For large `n`, some hash or other algorithmic computation is even faster.

Comment: @FelixPalmen even if the values are arbitrarily distributed, you can still arrange them in ascending order and divide them into groups of 2 repeatedly, effectively giving log(n) comparisons. Think of it like a completely balanced binary tree converted to a decision tree.

Comment: @chux, of course! Nothing beats a hash function, especially when the actual keys are known, one can always write a collision free hash function that is atleast as fast as O(log (n)).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya True,.  Even is the  actual key values are not known at coding time, auxiliary SW can divine an efficient hash function just prior to  compiler time with _make_.