# How to get relative string value from a Enum in C?

Tags: c, printf, enumeration

I have an Enum in C like the following:

```
typedef enum {
    idle,
    backup,
    charge,
} ENUM_LUMI_STATE;
```

and I have the following function:

```
ENUM_LUMI_STATE controllerGetState(void) {
    return idle;
}
```

I want to print it here:

```
printf("the current status of the system is %s \r\n", controllerGetState());
```

The resul is Obscure as you can see here:

> the current status of the system is þq st

I want to print the current status of the system is "idle".
Could you please tell me how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert enum names to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c)

Comment: Easiest is just to make a look-up table `const char* STR_LUMI_STATE[] = "idle", ....`. Then print `STR_LUMI_STATE[controllerGetState()]`.

Comment: @Gaurav Not really a great dupe, given that things like "X macros" should be the last resort, not the first. A plain string look-up table is sufficient in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

controllerGetState(void) function returns an enum and not a string. Therefore using %s for the return value will return garbage. You can use a %d to get the value, which will be 0 in this case.

Detailed answer is given in [How to convert enum names to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c)

Comment: But the OP wants to print a string, so I don't see how this answers the question?

Comment: The problem is similar to the one posed in the link I posted in my earlier comment. The solution to print string for an enum is elaborated there.