# Why is it returning 0 or 1 and not True or False

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef enum{
    False,
    True
}Bool;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a = 1, d = 1;
    Bool b = False, c = True;
    Bool ans;
    if (a == d)
    {
        ans = c;

    }
    else
    {
        ans = b;
    }
    printf("The answer is: %i \n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

I think it is only returning the execution result 0 or 1.
I want it to return the values from the enum which I created.

Comment: How do you think the values in your enum are represented internally?

Comment: If I change it to be TRuuue and Faaalse, it still returns 0 and 1.

Comment: Changing the names has absolutely *nothing* to do with Govind's question. Changing the *order* in the enum (`{ True, False }`) would be significant. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: In that case,  I am clueless.

Comment: also : [How to convert enum names to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907160/how-to-convert-enum-names-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to print the string `true` or `false` you'll have to add something like this:

```
printf("The answer is: %s\n", ans ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: Upped. Compared to my answer, this one is useful.

Comment: @Bathsheba Your answer is useful too. I gave you a +1 as it's more detailed.

Answer (score 2):

From the **[C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), § 6.7.2.2:2-3**:

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and
>   may appear wherever such are permitted.) An enumerator with = defines its
>   enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression. **If the first enumerator has
>   no =, the value ... is 0**. Each subsequent enumerator with no =
>   defines its ... value ... by
>   **adding 1 to the value of the previous enumeration constant**.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1):

In `C` an `enum` is no more than an `int` type but with special symbols for a subset of those `int`s. Also, unless you tell it otherwise, the implicit `int` value for the first `enum` member is 0, the second is 1, and so on.

`%i` can be used to print an `int`, which accounts for the output.

It is not possible to display the actual `enum` token in portable C, although there are idiomatic approaches that make use of the preprocessor.

Comment: The enum token can only be used in the program text.

Comment: Token names may also be available in debugging databases, depending on build settings (like a `.pdb` file on Windows)

Comment: A `enum` does not have to be a `int`.

Comment: A `enum` does no have to a `int` but can also be any integer type, which it can represent all values. *Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementationdefined, 128) but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration. ...* From 6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers - 4