# Need assistance with C macros and transformations

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a list of opcodes declared like this:

```
enum OpCode {
    PUSH = 0x01, 
    POP  = 0x02,
    DUP  = 0x03,
    //...etc (the list is too long to copy-paste it here and it wouldn't make a lot of sense)
}
```

What I want is to "automatically" (via macros):

- create an array of their string representations, like: `static const char *OpCodeStr[] = {"PUSH","POP","DUP",...};`
- create an array of some labels (for dispatch) using the different enum values, like: `static void* dispatchTable[] = {&&PUSH_, &&POP_, &&DUP_, ...};`

I believe it should be possible using C macros, but I still have not figured out how.

Any ideas?

Comment: you asked 2 questions. The first bullet can probably be solved with the duplicate I linked to. The other one is unclear. What is `&&PUSH_` ? an address of an address? Honestly you'd be better off with a script generating this stuff for you

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This for a computed-goto implementation (dispatch table for a bytecode interpreter).

Comment: the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966395/6451573 using x-macros can be applied to your problem, with 3 different blocks (the latter for your dispatch table)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I just solved it! Thanks!