# Passing an enum string (not value) to a macro

Tags: c++, enums, macros

So I had this query wherein say I have an enum and a struct that look like these,

```
enum fields {
   field_1,
   field_2
};

struct my_struct {
    int field_1;
    int field_2;
};
```

My specific need is, given the enum with the names of the structure members (field_1, field_2 etc) I should be able to generate a macro which can set the structure member to a given value.

```
#define my_macro (__a, __field) \
__a.__field = 1;
```

So is there a way to call my_macro like this:

```
struct my_struct b;
/* extract members of enum as string literals  */
my_macro(b, /*field name from the enum */);
```

Few other posts detailing usage of boost macros helps me extract the enum members as strings ( [How to convert an enum type variable to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093460/how-to-convert-an-enum-type-variable-to-a-string)). Issue is with passing it in the appropriate manner to the macro.

Comment: Well, did you try it?

Comment: Please select one language: C or C++.

Comment: Macros are evaluated and expanded at compile-time only.  If I am reading your question correctly, you are asking for something that is determined at runtime instead.  In which case, a macro will not work.  You need another solution, such as a `std::map` containing pointers to functions that know how to read/write the individual structure fields as needed.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? I think there may be a better way using the language instead of a macro.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That will not work in C.

Comment: @Olaf: a `std::map` will clearly not work in C, but a plain array of name+pointer pairs will.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You mean implementing a map as a module? Sure, but I think OP should first clarify which language he actually targets.

Comment: @Olaf : Apologies for the confusion in choice of language. C++ is fine, was hoping a solution that I'm unaware of might exist that could work with C too.

Comment: @simon_says: You should forget about that. While you **can** program C-like in C++, you actually should not. And even similar syntax might have subtle differences which can make debugging very difficult.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Regarding the first point you made, boost macros like BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE  will be evaluated/expanded at compile time itself. So  I was looking at using the info from these macros to achieve what I needed to do in my_macro, thus not having to bother with determination at run-time. (Have posted similar comment under Havenard's post)

Answer (score 1):

It should work the way it is. Macros are processed before compilation, while the code is still code, and they result in code generation.

Your macro `#define my_macro(__a, __field) __a.__field = 1;` will cause any entry like `my_macro(x, y)` to be transformed into `x.y = 1;`, literally, before its handed to the compiler.

If you do something like `my_macro(1+1, "test")`, it will generate the code `1+1."test" = 1;` and will create a compile error. Thats how simple macros are.

Thats why macro parameters are often enclosed by `()` to make sure it will work the way it was intented, if you don't do that things like this can happen:

```
#define div_by_100(a) a / 100

printf("%d\n", div_by_100(1000)); // will print 10
printf("%d\n", div_by_100(500 + 500)); // will print 505
```

This happens because order of operations is resolved at compile time, after the macros have been resolved.

Notice that, because macros are resolved before compilation, they are not a runtime solution. If this `enum` value is not explict in the code, macros won't help you at all. You will have to write a routing function that will assign a value to each member of this class/struct depending on what `enum` value was given. Example:

```
void route(struct farm* s, enum animals e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case cow:
            s->cow = 1;
            break;
        case duck:
            s->duck = 1;
            break;
        case horse:
            s->horse = 1;
            break;
        case goat:
            s->goat = 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way to pass output of one macro as-is to another macro. So in the example in the question, could output of BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(field_1) be used to pass as parameter to my_macro?

Comment: @simon_says You can pass a macro as parameter to another, no point in doing that in this case though. All this macro does is `#define BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(x) #x`, which converts `x` into `"x"`. You can use the same resource in your macro, but converting it to a string wont make it magically work, in fact it wont even compile.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way your mechanism of *turning an enum to a string* works. Your macro should work as long as that mechanism is still a macro that gets replaced by the preprocessor. That's the issue. Your macro should otherwise work properly.