# Enum missing cause compiler to error

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Following the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093460/how-to-convert-an-enum-type-variable-to-a-string):

```
enum class OS_type { Linux, Apple, Windows };

const std::string ToString(OS_type v)
{
    switch (v)
    {
        case Linux:   return "Linux";
        case Apple:   return "Apple";
        case Windows: return "Windows";
        default:      return "[Unknown OS_type]";
    }
}
```

I want to remove `default` and instead force compiler to generate error if the switch is not complete over my enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GCC / Clang**

You are looking for [-Wswitch-enum](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

> Warn whenever a switch statement has an index of enumerated type and
>   lacks a case for one or more of the named codes of that enumeration.
>   case labels outside the enumeration range also provoke warnings when
>   this option is used. The only difference between -Wswitch and this
>   option is that this option gives a warning about an omitted
>   enumeration code even if there is a default label.

```
const std::string ToString(OS_type v)
{
    // warning: enumeration value 'Windows' not handled in switch [-Wswitch-enum]
    switch (v)
    {
        case OS_type::Linux:   return "Linux";
        case OS_type::Apple:   return "Apple";
        default:      return "[Unknown OS_type]";
    }
}
```

Even default is used, it complains about the missing Windows enum. Just create the case for Windows and make a fallthrough to the default to suppress the enum.

**Visual Studio**

VS handles this at compiler level 3 and 4. You need to enable warning `C4061 / C4062`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/96f5t7fy.aspx