# C++11 Print run-time variable name equal to some constexpr variable

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way, using c++11, to get the name of a variable that is a (possibly static) constexpr.

For example:

```
struct Foo{
    int x, y, z;
};

constexpr Foo PrintMe = { 1, 2, 3};
```

I would like to get a string "PrintMe" somehow.

I know that I can use a macro like:

```
#define NAME_OF( v ) #v
```

and call

```
std::cout << NAME_OF(PrintMe) << std::endl;
```

which will print

> PrintMe

Is there a way to get the following print the same?

```
Foo a = PrintMe;

std::cout << Magic(a) << std::endl;
```

**EDIT**:
I am not looking for some magic solution which will make the call to `Magic(a)` work. I understand that doing something to accommodate what I want will require defining some macros or templates.
Like enums can be printed in some sort of way ([How to convert an enum type variable to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093460/how-to-convert-an-enum-type-variable-to-a-string)

Comment: What you are looking for is called reflection and it is not part of C++.

Comment: No. BTW what it has anything to do with `constexpr`. It is not possible in C++, irrespective of whether it is `constexpr` or not.

Comment: Also your title is misleading.  You have a way to print a compile time variable, you are looking to print a run time variable.

Comment: Why do think you want this?

Comment: The same could be said on any "How to print the name of an enum" but there are way of creating those enums in such a way that their names could be printed

Comment: @NathanOliver I changed the title, to better fit the question

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I want this for debug purposes

Comment: @ZivS: Your debugger already has this feature.

Comment: _"there are way of creating those enums in such a way that their names could be printed"_ Mmmm not really. Only to create a separate lookup. You can make that more convenient with macros, which is the same thing being claimed here.

Comment: Your edit contradicts the original question you asked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without macro, there is no way, no. You would have to do some kind of meta class in order to achieve this.

Comment: It doesn't exist yet, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0194r3.html for a proposal. Until then you need something outside the language that processes your source to generate extra information (such as Qt's `moc`)

Answer (score 0):

`Foo a = PrintMe;` has value semantics, it assigns the value of `PrintMe` to `a`. Afterwards, there is no way of checking whether this value came from `PrintMe`. Of course, you can check for the same value:

```
std::string Magic(const Foo& a) {
    if (a == PrintMe) { return NAME_OF(PrintMe); };
    else { /* whatever you want to happen here */ }
}
```

*But* this will of course also return `"PrintMe"` if you did

```
Foo a = {1, 2, 3};
```

Because the value is the same as `PrintMe`.