# Is it safe to use an enum to index an array?

Tags: c++, qt, enums

Is it safe to use an enum to index an array?
For example:

```
void messageToCerr( QtMsgType type,
                const QMessageLogContext& context,
                const QString& msg
              ) {
QVector<QString> typeName = {"Debug", "Warning", "Critical", "Fatal", "Info"};
QString output = QString( "[%1] %2" ).arg( typeName.at(type) ).arg( msg );
std::cerr << output.toStdString() << std::endl;
if ( type == QtMsgType::QtFatalMsg ) {

    abort();
}
```

}

Is using "type", which is

```
enum QtMsgType { QtDebugMsg, QtInfoMsg, QtWarningMsg, QtCriticalMsg, QtFatalMsg, QtSystemMsg }
```

like an array (vector) index is safe?
I read that traversing enum like array is unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are doing is safe given your definitions, but I'd suggest declaring/defining the vector at the time your creating the enum. So something like:

```
enum QtMsgType { QtDebugMsg, QtInfoMsg, QtWarningMsg, QtCriticalMsg, QtFatalMsg, QtSystemMsg };
QVector<QString> typeName = {"Debug", "Warning", "Critical", "Fatal", "Info"};
```

This will also make it abundantly clear that **your vector is wrong!** Notice how the enum has `Debug, Info, Warning, ...` and your vector is `Debug, Warning, Critical, ...`. Furthermore, there's no point in using a resizeable structure when it's a constant. As such, you can just have an array. Putting that all together would look like:

```
enum QtMsgType { QtDebugMsg, QtInfoMsg, QtWarningMsg, QtCriticalMsg, QtFatalMsg, QtSystemMsg };
QString typeName[] = {"Debug", "Info", "Warning", "Critical", "Fatal"};
```

Another option would be to overload the `<<` operator for streams for your `enum` and then stick all of the logic in there.

For more options, take a look at this thread: [How to convert an enum type variable to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5093460/2602718)

Comment: Side note there isn't much value in using a re-sizable data structure like `QVector` for a fixed size list. I'd add a `QtMsg_Last` or similar as the last entry in the enum. This gives you an easy value to use in a bounds check and a constant to use as the size of a `std::array`.

Comment: Good call @user. I've edited the array implementation in.