# How can i convert a enum to string without using array

Tags: c++, string, enums, converters

How to convert the enum below from int to string?

```
enum class EUserState :uint8
{
    Offline,
    Online,
    Busy,
    Away,
    Snooze,
    LookingToTrade,
    LookingToPlay, 
};
EUserState temp=EUserState::Online;
```

How to convert temp to a string without using a string array or something repeatly.
I don't want to make it cockamamie. 
Trying to find a automatic change? 
Can anyone help? :)

Comment: There are very few "automatic" things in C++, that the language will do for you. This isn't one of them. You must do all the work yourself. Using in array, or perhaps an external script that reads a YAML or XML enum definition and converts it to an enum declaration and code that maps it to a string.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828957/enum-to-string-in-modern-c11-c14-c17-and-future-c20)

Comment: More links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093460/how-to-convert-an-enum-type-variable-to-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment32807088_5093460 (...)

Comment: I don't think there's any "automatic change"!