# What does an associative array look like after HipHop PHP converts it to C++?

Tags: php, c++, hiphop

What does an associative array look like after HipHop PHP converts it to C++?

I was hoping someone that already compiled HipHop can tell me what this would look like:

```
$myAssoc = array('key'=>'value');

$myAssoc = array();
$myAssoc['key'] = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> myAssoc();
myAssoc["key"] = "value";
```

EDIT: Initialize with key-value pairs

I don't know if it made it into the standard library for C++11, but with you can accomplish this with [boost::assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of)

```
std::unordered_map<string, string> myAssoc = boost::assign::map_list_of("key1", "value1")("key2", "value2");
```

EDIT 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/340233/232574 shows `map_list_of` working on `std::unordered_map`

Comment: What about `array('key1' => 'value', 'key2' => 0)`?

Comment: yeah, what about that one, please?