# c alternate to enumeration for strings

Tags: c, string, enums

I was really hoping I could use enum's as follows

```
typedef enum {
    GPS_FULL_COLD = "$PMTK104*37",
    GPS_COLD = "$PMTK103*30",
    GPS_WARM = "$PMTK102*31",
    GPS_HOT = "$PMTK101*32"
} gps_start_mode;
```

so that I can have a function that type checks for a gps_start_mode and also has the value it needs. It seems however that c requires integral constants for enum values.

```
void configureStartMode(gps_start_mode mode) {
    gpsWrite(mode);
}
```

I was wondering if their is some other enum-like type I can use in place of enum here.

Otherwise, it seems I'll need to have a separate array to hold the string values, which isn't a huge hassle but not ideal.

Comment: Generally, `#define` operations are used instead.  Not as elegant, but folks have managed that way for decades.  Another technique is to use a numeric `enum` and then pass the `enum` value to a method that returns the corresponding string.

Comment: Using enum to hold indices to an array seems to be the best solution - it is simple and keeps type-checking, with cost of not-so-much boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually do this is to have an array of `const char *` containing strings that correspond to the elements in the enum.

The problem with this approach is that it is easy for the two data structures to become out-of-sync, for example if a new enum element is added, but the string array is not updated.

To provide some defensiveness against this, I add an additional element to the `enum`, which provides the number of elements in the enum. If the array of strings has `static` storage, then any elements not explicitly set, will automatically be set to `NULL`. You can therefore at least assert that the last element in the array is non-NULL resulting in immediate program termination if the string array has become out-of-sync with the enum.

Code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef enum gps_start_mode_
{
    GPS_FULL_COLD,
    GPS_COLD,
    GPS_WARM,
    GPS_HOT,
    gps_num_start_modes
}
gps_start_mode;

const char *start_mode_to_string[gps_num_start_modes] =
{
    "$PMTK104*37",
    "$PMTK103*30",
    "$PMTK102*31",
    "$PMTK101*32"
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   assert(start_mode_to_string[gps_num_start_modes - 1] != NULL);

   printf("Start mode %d is %s\n", GPS_HOT, start_mode_to_string[GPS_HOT]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got this far yesterday but weary of the out-of-sync issues I was hoping to go a little further and define the string array as: `const char *s_m_t_s[4];` and then `s_m_t_s[GPS_COLD] = "$PMTK...";` Which would guard me against the enum being rearranged. However I haven't found a way to do this that made the compiler happy.

Comment: Yup, there are some [pretty horrible solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207976/how-to-easily-map-c-enums-to-strings) to this involving variadic macros. It makes you realise the rationale behind the design of newer languages like Swift, which includes [more powerful enum support](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use #define directive for your requirements. Enums are not the solutions.
For #define directive. Eg.

```
#define key1 value1
#define key2 value2

int main(void){

  //your code here

  and remember all keys replaces their respecive value

}
```

**You can even define macros in between but the point is you can only use it below its definition.**

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it kills the type checking.