# Parse int from #define C++

Tags: c++, opengl

Assume the following code:

```
#define GL_DEPTH_TEST 0x0B71

std::string shader_args = "GL_DEPTH_TEST";
```

I want to run something like

```
glEnable(shader_args);
//Draw stuff
glDisable(shader_args);
```

I have tried std::atoi(shader_args) but it returns 0 instead of 0x0B71

Comment: `#define GL_DEPTH_TEST 0x0B71` is not an `enum`.   Sounds like you might want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207976/how-to-easily-map-c-enums-to-strings

Comment: Basically there's no easy way like in C#, only the hard ways (see dupe). Question is how did you end up with a string "GL_DEPTH_TEST" in the first place? Maybe that place can be improved.

Comment: Basically I want to have a shader to have rendering options like depth test and stencil test. I am trying different ways to implement this like passing the options via a string which is parsed then passed on to OpenGL for rendering. There is probably a better way to that. Hope to find out

Comment: Maybe you can generate the C++ code for that. If you take a list of all #defines, you can write a simple sed script to generate std::map code or something like that.