# Get enum value from key stored in a variable

Tags: c++, enums

If I have an enumeration like

```cpp
enum values {


   var1 = 12,

   var2 = 23,

   var3 = 34
};
```

is it possible to get the value from

```cpp
  string str = "var2";

  // Get values::str;
```

I have tried creating an enum variable and assigning the variable str to it, but this gives a type mismatch error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207976/how-to-easily-map-c-enums-to-strings

Comment: The names only exist at compile-time. You would have to add code to keep a runtime map of names to values if that's what you wanted .

Comment: No, not in C++. Some languages like Java and Typescript provide reflection capabilities to get the names and underlying data for enum constants, but in C++ they truly are integers with extra steps. None of that information is available at runtime.