# How to know which enum is currently running out of multiple enums

Tags: iphone

I am new to programming for the iPhone. In my project, I have an `enum` in a header file:

```
enum SelectionType
{

    BookSelection,
    StartChapter,
    EndChapter
}SType;
```

In my project, I want to know which `enum` I have right now. For that, I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
NSLog(@"stype is %c",SType);
```

Which format specifier should I use to get the enum in `NSLog`?

Comment: [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/202511/1320630), from a similar question, will let you solve this once. A series of macros that help you map between the enum value and it's string representation.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do it yourself.  C does not have this kind of reflection capability.  Here is a function you could use:

```
const char *STypeName(SType t)
{
    switch (t) {
    case BookSelection: return "BookSelection";
    case StartChapter: return "StartChapter";
    case EndChapter: return "EndChapter";
    default: return NULL;
    }
}
```

And then you can call the function `SelectionTypeName` to get the name:

```
SType stype = ...;
NSLog(@"stype = %s", STypeName(stype));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum SelectionType {

BookSelection==0,//system provide the default value 0 for first enum then increase by one.
StartChapter==1,
EndChapter==2
}SType;
//then you check with 

if(sType==0)
  {
 //do something
}


else if(sType==1)
{

}

else
{

}
//you can use 
NSLog(@"Enum number=%i",sType);
```

Answer (score 0):

enum is basically int data type. You should use %d format specifier.