# Converting from String to Enum in C

Tags: c, string, enums

Is there a convienent way to take a string (input by user) and convert it to an Enumeration value?  In this case, the string would be the name of the enumeration value, like so:

```
enum Day
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    ...
}
```

So that if the user gave the name of a Day, it would be able to parse that to the corresponding Enum value.

The trick is, I have over 500 values I'm working with, and they are spread out across multiple enumerations.

I know of the Enum.Parse Method in c#, so is there some form of this in c?

Comment: How do you want to relate strings and enumerations?

Comment: the string would be the name of the enumeration value.

Comment: Short answer: no, there's no "convenient" way, but you can probably get what you want through a tricky use of macros. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147267/easy-way-to-use-variables-of-enum-types-as-string-in-c

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201593/is-there-a-simple-script-to-convert-c-enum-to-string?rq=1

Comment: Do you really have to use straight C? std::map<std::string, Day> would be *ideal* for this.

Comment: haha, yeah.  I'm modifying source code (10000+ lines) to implement new features.  Already did it once in c# and it went quite smoothly.  I think this ones gonna be ugly though

Comment: You could still use a separate C++ source file to implement the `map`, and provide `extern "C"` interfaces to allow the C code to do the lookup. It is unclear to me how you want the implementation to scale. Are you willing to change how you declare your enumerations to make a solution work?

Comment: I don't think that is an option.  Currently, as I understand it, the values for the enumerations are coming from a file that has one massive array (of the names, values, and properties of the soon to be enums).  That file is generated in the prebuild.  My boss recommended that I use that file, compare the strings of the names, and generate hash functions that way

Comment: use gperf (too lazy for a proper answer right now)

Comment: @Nealon: Ah, so using an external tool to perform code generation for you is acceptable. Then, @PerJohansson's suggestion of `gperf` combined with a hash table can be done, you just need a script to generate the appropriate code for you.

Comment: @user315052 yes, we are using nant to build everything and generate files for xmls and such.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The standard way to implement it is something along the lines of:

```
typedef enum {value1, value2, value3, (...) } VALUE;

const static struct {
    VALUE      val;
    const char *str;
} conversion [] = {
    {value1, "value1"},
    {value2, "value2"},
    {value3, "value3"},
       (...)
};

VALUE
str2enum (const char *str)
{
     int j;
     for (j = 0;  j < sizeof (conversion) / sizeof (conversion[0]);  ++j)
         if (!strcmp (str, conversion[j].str))
             return conversion[j].val;    
     error_message ("no such string");
}
```

The converse should be apparent.

Comment: honestly, I'm a little lost, can you clarify what this does a bit?

Comment: @Nealon:  It sets up a data structure which associates each string value with a corresponding enum value.  The conversion function looks for a string match and returns the corresponding enum value.

Comment: so its like making a dictionary in C#?

Comment: Maybe `const char *str;` instead of `char *str;`.  Compiler might detect some wrong uses during this development.

Comment: @chux:  a fair tweak if using a modern compiler, which probably will give a useful warning to the same effect.  I've modified it anyway.

Comment: It's worth noting that this algorithm is O(n) on the number of possible enum values. If you're really just doing the days of the week, this will be fine, but if you have an enum with e.g. 100 possible values, and you're calling this function a large number of times, it might add up.

Answer (score 4):

Warning, this is a total hack. You can use `dlsym` to do a lookup of a variable that is appropriately initialized. For this example to work, you have to compile to allow local symbols to be visible to the dynamic linker. With GCC, the option is `-rdynamic`.

```
enum Day {
    SunDay, MonDay, TuesDay, WednesDay, ThursDay, FriDay, SaturDay
};

enum Day Sunday = SunDay,
         Monday = MonDay,
         Tuesday = TuesDay,
         Wednesday = WednesDay,
         Thursday = ThursDay,
         Friday = FriDay,
         Saturday = SaturDay;

int main () {
    const char *daystr = "Thursday";
    void *h = dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW);
    enum Day *day = dlsym(h, daystr);
    if (day) printf("%s = %d\n", daystr, *day);
    else printf("%s not found\n", daystr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Daring!  But could come in handy when I feel lazy.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a direct way, but with C, you improvise. Here's an old trick. Purists may balk at this. But it's a way to manage this kind of stuff somewhat sanely. Uses some preprocessor tricks.

In constants.h put in the following:

```
CONSTANT(Sunday,  0)
CONSTANT(Monday,  1)
CONSTANT(Tuesday, 2)
```

In main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONSTANT(name, value) \
    name = value,

typedef enum {
    #include "constants.h"
} Constants;

#undef CONSTANT

#define CONSTANT(name, value) \
    #name,

char* constants[] = {
    #include "constants.h"
};  

Constants str2enum(char* name) {
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < sizeof(constants) / sizeof(constants[0]); ++ii) {
        if (!strcmp(name, constants[ii])) {
            return (Constants)ii;
        }   
    }   
    return (Constants)-1;
}   

int main() {
    printf("%s = %d\n", "Monday", str2enum("Monday"));
    printf("%s = %d\n", "Tuesday", str2enum("Tuesday"));
    return 0;
}
```

You can try other variations of the basic idea.

Comment: +1. As for a variation, if you use a `struct` to associate the string to the `enum` value, you could `qsort()` the array, and use `bsearch()` to do the lookup.

Comment: Whenever someone mentions "preprocessor tricks", I usually grit my teeth because such associated code is usually challenging to read and very challenging to debug.  I understand the appeal of this kind of thing, but have pity for those who have to maintain it.

Comment: I do like it, but the enumerations are predefined and I'm not allowed to modify them.

Comment: Yes, the appeal of this approach is in actually being able to define a real enum, and an array of strings, that automatically keep in sync. Otherwise, just use answer by @wallyk. But having this technique in your toolbox can be useful - in spite of what wallyk says above :) It actually makes things more clear and maintainable (once you understand what's going on). And there are other possibilities. Like expanding the include file in the context of a switch statement, to implement dispatchers etc. Kind of like code generation.

Comment: @Nealon:  I meant for the person who has to work on the code two years after you have left.  A standard C programmer is unlikely to have seen this before, so she will be puzzled for some time until understanding it dawns.

Comment: @wallyk My post went down before I had seen yours, no worries, no judgments were made.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using straight C, there isnt a "Enum.Parse" equivalent. You'll want to write your own function, comparing the user's string to pre-defined values with `strcmp()`, and then returning the appropriate enum value.

Another possibility is using an existing "hash map" implementation, or rolling your own - for instance, the one in glib should work for you: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Hash-Tables.html

A hash map should be faster than doing a linear search on the possible enum values, if you have a lot of them (for instance, if you were doing something other than the days of the week). A good hash map implementation should be close to O(1) for lookups, instead of O(n) for a linear search.

Comment: I have 500+ plus values across multiple enumerations I'm working with.  I'll update my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, though if you use a hash function you can setup all of the values of your enum to match a set of hashed strings. You might have to use a more complicated hash if you don't care about case-sensitivity.

This is probably your best solution, since it has lower overhead than strcmp (...). The assignment of an enum value from a string hash does not require repeated string comparisons, etc...

Comment: using a hash would definitely be the least expensive option, and judging from the scale of this, I think that will be the way to go.  I'll have to generate separate hash functions for each enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a good solution :

```
enum e_test { a, b, c, END };

enum e_test get_enum_value(char * val) {
    static char const * e_test_str[] = { "a", "b", "c" };
    for (int i = 0; i < END; ++i)
        if (!strcmp(e_test_str[i], val))
            return i;
    return END;
 }
```